# What single change would have given the best chance for the Axis to win World War 2?

Tags: science-based, alternate-history

A common topic in alternate history fiction works is what would have happened if a major war had been won by the other side. These usually focus on the events after the war, and the change itself is not depicted realistically: it's either not discussed, or attributed to a superweapon or deus ex machina.

I know that WW2 was a very complex war, with a huge number of social and economic factors in it so that there was no single realistic "miracle" which would have guaranteed a certain different outcome. Therefore I list a number of disclaimers in order to make this question fit into the topic of this site.

- It doesn't have to guarantee an Axis victory, but it has to increase its probability significantly.
- A victory doesn't necessarily mean global domination (which neither power had any realistic chance of achieving). If Germany ends up in control over most of Eastern Europe (like the Soviets ended up doing in real life after the war), with a Soviet Union unwilling to fight, and with a peace treaty with the western Allies at least slightly favorable to Germany, it counts as a victory for Germany.
- The change has to be a single event, or a collection of tightly coupled and interdependent events. It has to happen either during the war, or not more than a few years before it. The war should, at least in the beginning, look very similar to what happened in real life: the alliances should be roughly the same, the events like the conquest of Poland, the occupation of France, an attack against the Soviet Union, and a naval war between the USA and Japan should occur (or at least begin), even if at different dates or different order. The major participants should be the same.
- The change should have a realistic justification (so no secret Nazi super laser), I would think in the following changes: events progressing slightly faster or slightly slower than in real life, a single large battle or series of interconnected battles won by the opposite side (if that had even a small chance of happening)

I'm thinking along the lines of Germany and its allies advancing faster against the Soviets and crushing them before they had any chance of putting up a good defense, or Hitler not antagonizing scientists so they could develop even better equipment or maybe even a nuclear bomb, or Japan winning the battle of Midway and keeping the USA from entering the European theater, or a different sequence of diplomatic events leading a peace on one front which in turn could lead to a victory on the other front, etc.

Comment: The nazis not invading Poland and thus turning the USSR against them.

Comment: The axis chances were actually not that great, they started with a huge standing army sure, but couldn't keep up with the rate the others could build up forces so it was just a matter of time until attrition took them down.  The biggest change though would be a simple one, never attack Russia!  They lost allot to Russian winter, and having an extra flank to defend divided what forces they had.  I don't know rather or not it alone would have saved them, but I know avoiding attacking Russia would be a huge boon, and doesn't require a spectactical change, someone realized it was crazy

Comment: I'd go with  "not invading Russia" -- Napoleon.

Comment: Considering that this question already has 20+ answers, it makes me appreciate history way more knowing that there were so many pivotal points during the war, and that any minor changes could have swung the victory in the opposite direction. I know with the benefit of hindsight it's easy to see what went right/wrong, and if things had happened differently at the time the other side would have reacted differently to counter it etc., but it's fascinating to think that the outcome of the conflict was balanced on a knife edge. +1

Comment: May I recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Hinge-Factor-Stupidity-Changed-History/dp/0340728302) for a fascinating "small moment" that might have prevented the Dunkirk evacuation?

Comment: Perhaps Hitler not focusing _that much_ on trying to gain the mythical superpowers and dei ex machinae? :-)

Comment: related: [What if the attack on Pearl Harbour had been averted in World War 2?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/what-if-the-attack-on-pearl-harbour-had-been-averted-in-world-war-2?rq=1), [What if Germany had atomic bombs in WWII](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22263/what-if-germany-had-atomic-bombs-in-wwii?rq=1), [What is the smallest change one could make within the past two hundred years to save the most lives?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22709/what-is-the-smallest-change-one-could-make-within-the-past-two-hundred-years-to?rq=1)

Comment: What’s not been suggested and I’m not knowledgable enough about: 1. Death of Stalin before 1943 results in Soviet/Russian civil war. 2. Franco’s Spain joins forces with Germany and Italy in 1940 or 1941, takes Gibraltar.

Comment: Funny, we have a whole Stack Exchange spin-off for history, but this question would get crucified there.

Comment: anyone performing time travel. Regardless of the reason or destination, if Holywood has taught us anything it's that time travel of any kind causes the nazi's to win WWII : http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GodwinsLawOfTimeTravel

Comment: Lots of good stuff here and 'some' rubbish :-). Consider looking at the many things which seem to have helped the allies win. You can find a large number of things which by themselves almost seem to have made THE difference. Knock out a good number and it may turn the tide.| Hitlers obstinate no-retreat fighj where you stand approach - good sometimes, more often fatal | Chamberlain won the war with Munich! - he gave them the extra year needed to gave them the Spitfire which swung the Battle of Britain which forstalled Sealion which ... ...

Comment: ... . (Hurricane was better than most credit it being - but not enough. |  -  Churchill was more human than many seem to realise but made a vast difference ... . C' dead = ...? | Enigma - your code has been broken - Imbeciles! | The bomb, as has been said. | Malta - agh - eliminate Malta and you have the Mediterranean and ... |. Realise how crucial African front is and resource it well enough. Small compared with other demands (even though the rest ever so urgent).Egypt gives you Palestine gives Caucasus access to Eastern oil fields gives ... - India was a major Britsh food source. | Much more

Comment: If the Bletchley Park four had never written their letter to Churchill, or Churchill never read it, or never acted on it.  That Churchill did act on it, overriding his own generals and advisors is pretty surprising, so ignoring it is actually the more likely course.  Almost every answer here could have been undone by Bletchley Park anyway ... *unless* Churchill never gave them the resources that they were being denied.

Comment: The keys of WWII are US resource committment and Germany's invasion of the Soviet Union. If US involvement had not taken place, or Germany had defeated the USSR, Germany would have been very difficult to remove from Western Europe. **_The key is Japan's entry into the war by attacking Russia instead of the USA_**. That would have both kept the US out of the war for some time and prevented the USSR from moving their Far East divisions. Siberian oil and mines would have given Japan interior lines of supply, and Western hatred of Communism reducing the amount of support offered to the USSR.

Comment: Here is a great compilation of all the things Hitler screwed up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK419Nlp8eU Basically, if he wasn't an idiot he could have won.

Comment: Further reading: Philip Roth - The Plot Against America

Comment: Please check out the book The Man In the High Castle by Philip K Dick. Excellent read. I believe they talked about how the US stayed very very firm to its isolationist policy, thus they couldn't mobilize or build up their armies or defenses, resulting in the Axis easily coming through to defeat them. Great new tv series with the same name is out there as well.

Comment: Is it acceptable to remove Hitler pre-war? He was a decent demagogue but a poor leader in terms of policy, diplomacy and strategy. Also, not having the Holocaust would have alienated far less of the world. Imperialism and war was still "usual" at the time, and WWII would probably have happened, anyway, what with the terms of the treaty of Versailles (the dissatisfaction with which Hitler used and fueled but did not create) hanging over Germany.

Comment: Would bottling up Pearl Harbor by successfully blocking the harbor entry with the *Nevada* have made a big enough difference? From what I recall, if the harbor entrance had been blocked with a shipwreck, most of the US naval fleet would have been trapped, severely limiting the US's ability to take part in the war for about 6 months. And it's a very viable "small change" that would cause major changes in the timeline.

Comment: An extremely important decision was done by Stalin in the beginning of 30-s: to develop new industrial areas to the east from Ural as opposed to that in Ukraine. If it was Ukraine, it would be occupied by German in the first weeks of the war. With the loss of the majority of industrial power, the war would be lost by USSR.

Comment: Not invade Russia. Or at least not invade when they did is obvious. But what would be the alternative? Turn to the middle east and cut off the allies supplies of oil and gas. Invade the Levant, Iraq and then Iran. Threaten India.

Comment: "The nazis not invading Poland and thus turning the USSR against them."
@Jake: Germany and USSR invaded Poland together, they where allies that time. Later, Germany attacked USSR (attacked an ally).
Seems that Hitler thought that Stalin would attak him if he was not faster.

Comment: @JulianEgner Yes, invading Poland did not turn USSR against Germany. Tho it did turn Britian/France against Germany. Hitler thought that they wouldn't make good on their threat. In fact, Hitler never planned to make war with Britain as he envisioned a British Empire alongside his German One, which is one reason why he had too few U-Boats in 1940.

Comment: Regarding the old answer that Hitler shouldn't have invaded USSR, however, did that to try to get to the Caucasus oil fields. The question is, would he have run out of oil if he hadn't done that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because given the number of valid answers it has received it's definitely too broad. Furthermore it's being referenced as an example of what is currently ok. For the sake of a consistent site experience this should be closed to not confuse newcomers to the site.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that "Hitler not being an idiot" would be too big a change. The most effective suggestions made seem to involve that.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

#### Idea

I agree with many other answerers that one major factor in the Reich losing the war was Hitler. So it's reasonable to affect a change that removes him from the picture. I like the [proposal for him to have served in logistics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/30792/3657) with the consequence that he would have been a more competent war leader. However, his other issues are unlikely to change.

I want to work from the following idea: there was considerable unrest in Germany when Hitler assumed power. Economy was down and the terms of the Versailles treaty were generally considered unfair. Short of a diplomatic resolution of this tension (not really the spirit of the time), war was inevitable. Given the situation, any skilled demagogue could have come to power.

So we let Hitler do this: let him come to power, unite the people behind his figure and prepare Germany for war. Then, limit his power so far that he can not hinder the war effort, ruin most international relations, and make the Reich a bad guy. Do not remove him completely -- he *is* a rally point -- but limit his influence.

#### Proposal

*Disclaimer:* I am not a historian. Any serious attempt at producing a believable piece of alternate fiction based on *small* changes will have to be the result of extensive research.

Have the [Blomberg–Fritsch Affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blomberg%E2%80%93Fritsch_Affair) in 1938 turn out differently. It becomes known in the party that Hitler had the thing set up to get rid of rivals. As a consequence, power shifts within the leading elite. While Hitler remains chancellor/president for appearances sake, his role degrades to a representative figurehead -- the real decisions are made elsewhere.

Rationale on why this influences the war effort in ways positive for the Reich:

- Most of the preparation (arguably only possible with the somewhat crazy dedication of Hitler's) has already been finished. The armed forces are well-trained, well-equipped and ready.
- Military leadership remains effective and competent. Other answers discuss multiple ways in which that helps.
- International relations will be handled in a more rational way.
  [Appeasement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeasement) does not break completely, and the Reich does not attack everybody at once.
- The Holocaust (a pet project of Hitler's) does not happen. This saves resources and causes less internal and international dissent, in particular post-war.

#### Perspective

It seems likely that much of what constitutes the EU today, with the possible exclusion of Great Britain, would have fallen under the rule of the Reich (which it pretty much *was* in the real time line, at some point during the war).

Looking forward, a non-Hitler Reich may not have been as scary a prospect as as the Hitler Reich we've seen in our real history. It may have actually been stable after the war, at least for some years. The US may not have entered the European theater at all. The biggest conflict would probably have been between the Reich and Stalin's USSR in case it did not fall during the war. It is somewhat plausible that we'd have gotten a Cold War similar to what we actually got, but with different parties: the Reich, the USSR, and maybe the US.

Comment: I was thinking about accepting either the bomb or the assassination answers, then I saw this. I guess the low number of votes is only due to it arriving late, ending up on the second page, and not enough people noticing it. I'm accepting this answer now, but please comment whether it contains some major drawbacks and if so, I'll revise my decision. What I like in this answer the most is that it preserves the original participants the most. Hitler was a very strong rally point and inspiration for his followers, so keeping him active as a figurehead might be more effective than killing him.

Comment: Also, if he is not reduced to a figurehead but retains his power, but listens to his advisers and generals more than he did in real life, the scenarios in this answer also seem plausible. Good point about the Holocaust, but I think it still would have happened, but in a significantly milder form. There was already a huge mistrust against Jews, due to them perceived to have too much power and influence (very wealthy bankers, and their over-representation in important positions relative to their percentage of the population), but confiscating the fortunes of some of the wealthiest and and ...

Comment: ... and maybe exiling  or resettling some of the more powerful Jews instead of creating the concentration camps might have satisfied the anti-semitic part of the population while not hindering the diplomacy options for Germany that much. This answer might also lead them discovering the bomb first, or among the first, but not required to use it recklessly. A decapitation strike against the Soviets, while not using it against the Western allies at all might have helped. (think about the proposals of some British at the end of the war IRL to re-arm Germany and march them against the Soviets)

Comment: @vsz I'm glad you like my answer! Regarding the Holocaust, that's an item requiring more research. My interpretation/feeling is that without the intense agitation by Hitler et al., the population would never have stood for the Holocaust. In fact, few even knew of it; it was mostly carried out in secret. The official story *was* one of resettling. Some looking-away happened, for sure, but no voting for it or anything, at least by the majority of the population.

Comment: I like this, Hitler wasn't really dumb or even apart from few blind spots ignorant, the problem was that his mental state deteriorated to the point where it was unwise for people to disagree with him, which led to lots of very bad decisions. It is actually a common phenomenon not limited to Hitler, although his personality was probably a bad fit for absolute power. So I'd totally believe that having Hitler somehow "checked" behind the scenes so that he **has to** listen to advice or even delegate some decisions outright would greatly improve the chances of victory.

Comment: While it is true that the holocaust was driven by the nazis and Hitler personally. I think you need to spread the responsibility wider. It is not just the amount of support for holocaust that matters, but also the lack of support for resisting it. IIRC, the Greeks and the Dutch (?) had to be forced by German occupation and Finland actually, due to not being occupied, just said no. But in most of Europe Jews and other targeted groups were considered expendable. It wouldn't have happened without Hitler, yes, but there wasn't popular support for **protecting** targeted groups either.

Comment: What this means is that there was widespread prejudice and those groups were accepted as different and separate. Not part of **us** that should be protected.

Comment: In Finland and Greece the Jewish minority was well integrated to the general population and local governments, despite being on the same side as the nazis, simply did not see them as separate population or as a problem to be removed. So the governments tried to protect them the same as other citizens.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Your comments about resposibility for the holocaust miss the mark here. I'm not trying to shift blame; I'm trying to estimate how the war would have gone had Hitler not have as much influence as he did. I think it's plausible that the holocaust may not have happened, existing prejuidice notwithstanding, which in turn would have changed how other players dealt with the Reich.

Comment: @Raphael Yeah, I got that, all I am saying that there was a pre-existing condition in much of Europe that made it possible, namely the prejudice and perception as "separate and different" against groups such as Jews, Gypsies, homosexuals, and so on. Even with Hitler "reduced" the leaders would still have been Nazis, right? So with "spreading the blame" I actually mean that it might have been too late to avoid holocaust at that point. It might have been more like the pogroms that preceded it with less resources and industrial efficiency, but I doubt it would have gone away.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Maybe not. The point is antagonism. As long as minorities would have been treated only slightly worse in the Reich than in other countries, nobody would have cared too much. (It's also a matter of who writes history; it's not as if Stalin had not had lots of people killed.) But again, the point here is not to discuss the Holocause more than in its role as antagonizing factor w.r.t. the war.

Comment: @Raphael True, I think we got off on a bit off a tangent here. Seems to be a common hazard when the holocaust comes up. But one thing that I'll still mention: even with the holocaust happening most governments didn't really do much beyond refusing to return refugees to German control. Even helping people out was AFAIK up to the personal initiative of diplomats. So not sure how much difference the holocaust actually did in the political situation during the war. It might have been part of why Churchill and Roosevelt were willing to help Stalin and why Finland didn't help conquer Leningrad...

Comment: Without wanting to be to harsh, I would like to point that the general idea of "German generals competent but were overruled by incompetent Hitler" has come under criticism lately. Some of Hitler decisions overruling his generals did make sense (defend in Stalingrad while the army in the Caucasus retreats, do not retreat to the middle of nowhere in the Soviet 1941 offensive) and his generals supported some of his bad ideas (specially invading the Soviet Union). But after the war, his generals could write books blaming Hitler and absolving themselves while Hitler could not do the same.

Comment: I feel like if this were the case, a WWII with the Allies fighting alongside the Reich against the Soviet Union might not be out of the question either.

Answer (score 138):

## Germany completes the Uranprojekt first

Germany, prior to the Nazi takeover, had the best physics research establishment in the world, bar none.

Imagine that the discoverers of fission, [Hahn and Strassmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Hahn) instead of ignoring [Ida Noddak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ida_Noddack)'s suggestions for 4 years (as they do in our timeline), work with her and [Lise Meitner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lise_Meitner) to discover nuclear fission  early in 1933 instead of 1938. The [Heereswaffenamt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffenamt), the Nazi equivalent of the American Skunk Works/DARPA , manages to catch the paper before it reaches publication stage, and Hitler immediately recognizes the potential of the weapon.

Uranprojekt is thus started under absolute secrecy 5 years early, and funded to a level equivalent to the Reichsautobahn (highway) project. Hundreds of German scientists disappear from public view and are tasked to work on the Uranprojekt full time. They focus on simpler gun-type designs, starting uranium enrichment as early as 1935, with hundreds of kilograms of enriched uranium generated before the war's start. Germany reaches deployable nuclear weapons in 1938.

[image: Da bomb]

A corresponding logical focus on developing heavy, [long-range bombers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerika_Bomber) enables them to deploy the bomb at considerable range, in the Schwerer Bomber Messerschmitt Me 264.

[image: Messer Bomber]

> The Amerika-Bomber project was an initiative of the German Reichsluftfahrtministerium to obtain a long-range strategic bomber for the Luftwaffe that would be capable of striking the contiguous United States from Germany, a distance of about 5,800 km (3,600 mi).

The allies crumble in a matter of months under the German Bomb.

[image: Statue of Liberty]

Comment: I came here to post "the Nazi get da bomb first", but your essay is a piece of art. well done sir.

Comment: In a delicious turn of history, it was Lisa Meitner's Jewish heritage, and the persecution that she endured at the hands of the Nazi government, that probably delayed the discovery of fission by years, and thus maybe prevented a successful German Atom Bomb project in our world.

Comment: Related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/22293/6751

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32488/discussion-on-answer-by-serban-tanasa-what-single-change-would-have-given-the-mo).

Comment: In retrospect, the difference in some event, like a failure of Operation Gunnerside (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_heavy_water_sabotage#Operation_Gunnerside) could allow the Nazis to make the bomb.

Comment: I have to voice my disagreement. Building nuclear bombs is a difficult business, it took all of America's industry and focus (along with Germany's exiled Jewish scientists) to make it a reality by 1945, and even then they only managed to build two bombs by the August of that year. If Japan had kept the fight up, America would have had no more bombs to drop, at least for a while. For Germany a bomb may have been a deterrent for America's involvement in the war in Europe, but that alone would be unlikely to affect the outcome of the war. Very easily the A-bomb could've proven to be a V-weapon

Comment: @Mints97: it could have allowed the Nazis to make _some_ kind of nuclear bomb, but such bombs probably wouldn't have changed the war much. Slowing down neutrons is a good strategy when you're designing a reactor that can be huge and heavy and is supposed to work smoothly. But even with heavy water, this doesn't really allow an effective bomb design; at best the Nazis could have used the heavy water to breed more radioactive isotopes more quickly, and perhaps build some really nasty _dirty bombs_, and those are pretty good for terror but not very effective against industrial infrastructure.

Comment: Did they also move the Statue of Liberty too? Because you can't see the Brooklyn Bridge behind the statue.

Comment: @Stumbler, that's why I have them starting well before the war, and funding it to the level of the massive highway project.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa interestingly Germany was bad at focusing on really useful projects until the last minute. The fighter jet, main battle tank, infantry launched anti-tank rocket, inter-continental missile, etc. were all back-burner projects until their introduction was deemed imperative (the Germans were shocked that their tanks were sub par when they attacked the USSR and had to quickly produce something that could counter the T-34). Something like the fission bomb would never do as a back-burner project suddenly kicked into life in the event of an emergency.

Comment: Germany actually wins World War 2? I did *Nazi* that coming!

Comment: @WorldSpinner: And the *Wurst* Prize for alternate-reality fascist victory puns goes to...

Comment: @Stumbler: That apparent lack of foresight was a result of the high command being *aware*, *well* before the whole war kicked off, that they had no chance of winning the war by attrition. The plan was to defeat Russia by surprise attack, within one year or two at the most. They intended to win the war *without* having to put the whole nation into "wartime production" state.

Comment: @stumbler - the Nazi's were *very* close to producing nuclear weapons. Yes they may have been "dirty" bombs - but drop a few of those on London/Manchester/Birmingham/New York/Philadelphia and the UK/US would have sued for peace pretty damn quickly. You don't have to destroy a nation's ability to wage war, just their will to.

Comment: @Stumbler - Uranium enrichment is just too slow. The Manhattan Project waited for a long time just to get enough U-235 for a single gun-type bomb. They  accurately concluded that plutonium bombs were necessary to produce bombs at a higher rate -- this required a complete redesign to use implosion. Though a more complex design., the US would have been able build 2-3 plutonium bombs per month very soon after the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombs (within 30-60 days), and actually had plans to use them on Japan - Truman put a stop to those plans.

Comment: Just to let you know: the US project to build the B-29 superfortress **cost more than the Manhattan Project** (so heavy long-range bombers are a huge, huge industrial thing). To do both that and the A-Bomb, and both within 5 years, would cost more resources than Germany had in 1935-1940. Germany was very much a war-torn and despondent nation after WW1.

Comment: And to be thorough, we also need to figure out **where and how a huge supply of Uranium** will come from to do intense research. America got lucky with the Shinkolobwe Mine in Africa. Only 3 other known Uranium sources existed: Czechoslovakia, Colorado, and The Great Slave Lake in Canada. None of those 3 had anywhere near the rich deposit of Uranium in Shinkolobwe. I recommend this book if you're interested: Uranium: War, Energy, and the Rock That Shaped the World, by Tom Zoellner.

Answer (score 92):

**Assassinate Hitler**
In 1941, mid war, Hitler is assassinated with the hope that this would weaken the German top ranks, cause infighting, hurt morale, and bring a faster end to the war.

Instead Erich von Manstein is able to seize control quickly and stop the march against Russia. Using this as a way to open ceasefire talks, they are able to avoid having to fight on as many fronts, directing more forces against England and the allies.
The "martyrdom" of Hitler also doesn't hurt morale as hoped, but give the German soldiers something to rally behind.

This gives them time to dig in, which brings the allies to the negotiation table to work out an end to the war.

Score: draw (but not a loss, satisfying bullet point 2).

**Edit:**
After a bit more reading, it's possible, even likely, that Germany would still have attacked Russia if Hitler was killed in 1941, but some historians believe that it would have been successful (as it very nearly was) if Hitler had listened to his generals and focused Moscow first, instead of trying for the oil fields first.

**Continued:** [(disclamer, I got a lot of what follows here if you want to skip to the source)](http://www.militaryhistoryonline.com/wwii/articles/invadingrussia.aspx)
tl;dr: Why might they attack Russia? They needed oil. Their choices were to attack the British in Egypt on the way to the middle east, or attack Russia. Russia was the stronger of the two, and was massing troops along the border. The theory was that Russia could attack in the summer of 42, so they decided to attack first, before Russia was ready. And Russia was not ready at all. Despite Having a bigger army, they had poor leadership (Stalin killed a lot of the best officers), poor communication, and poor training.
Germany had victory after victory in Russia, capturing or killing millions of Russian soldiers. They got within 20 miles of Moscow before winter. They just couldn't push that last little bit.
The reason is that Hitler wanted to take the oil fields first, depriving the Russians of the resources, while the generals want to take Moscow first in order to remove the Russian leadership, and they could only put their main power behind one. Half way through Hitler decided the generals plan was better, but it was to late, and they didn't make it before winter. Russia was able to bring in more troops and push them back, hurting them badly.
Without Hitler the generals would have put the main push against Moscow and probably would have been able to take it by September.

**Edit 2**
Since comments were moved to chat, there have been some good comments about Germany attacking Russia that improve the answer

> Mints97
>   just my couple of cents here: taking Moscow may not have necessarily meant taking Russia. Napoleon took Moscow, but he was as far from conquering Russia as he was when he started his invasion...

Agreed, and that's specifically why Hitler didn't want to focus on Moscow. He wanted to avoid the mistake that Napoleon made, and go after the resources first. For some reason his military leaders thought that Moscow was important, and managed to convince him to switch. Maybe it would have been better to stick to his original plan, or maybe they had information I don't know about.
I remember reading that the communist Russian army under Stalin was not very good at taking initiative, since he killed all the independent thinking ones that might try to take over. It wasn't the same Russia that Napoleon invaded.
It's possible that with the government gone that the army would have just folded up. Or maybe not. Another what-if.

Comment: Plus, the one of the Allies' greatest weapons against the German war machine was Hitler's incompetence as a military leader. His "strategies" got to the point where the British government actually stopped trying to assassinate him because they realized that he was winning the war for them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32489/discussion-on-answer-by-andyd273-what-single-change-would-have-given-the-most-ch).

Comment: @Simpson17866: Got any sources for that statement?

Comment: Moscow was a better target, at least preliminary. There are huge rail hubs and communication hubs and other roads all leading to Moscow. In 1812, there were no railways... Taking and holding, or at least surrounding Moscow like they did Leningrad, would be a huge boost. But remember their factories were evacuated to the Urals and Stalin brought in many fresh troops from Siberia (which is one major reason why the USSR **halted** the approach to Moscow), so it's not over yet.

Comment: @DrZ214 More good info! Yeah, I wonder if they would have been able to take Moscow before winter if they had moved against it first, instead of taking the route that Hitler wanted... If they had gotten in before the new troops had arrived. They may have been able to hold it through the winter if they were inside and the Russian troops were out in the cold. Or maybe not.

Comment: @AndyD273 I encourage you to search youtube for "lecture barbarossa" and similar things. Lot's of good data from professors there. In particular, Hitler actually changed his mind several times during the invasion, losing time as some armies fickley zig-zagged back and forth between north and south. Personally I think Stalin still woulda brought in reinforcements whenever Hitler got close enough. Moscow could have turned into a Stalingrad. In any case, there is no way the Army woulda survived the winter without the clothing, and they cannot get it from Moscow without walking into a Stalingrad.

Comment: Without wanting to be to harsh, I would like to point that the general idea of "German generals competent but were overruled by incompetent Hitler" has come under criticism lately. Some of Hitler decisions overruling his generals did make sense (defend in Stalingrad while the army in the Caucasus retreats, do not retreat to the middle of nowhere in the Soviet 1941 offensive) and his generals supported some of his bad ideas (specially invading the Soviet Union). But after the war, his generals could write books blaming Hitler and absolving themselves while Hitler could not do the same.

Comment: "the gov't" would have just relocated to another city, as it was done in RL anyway, to the city Kuibyshev IIRC (Stalin stayed back in Moscow in RL, would just leave it to same Kuibyshev if it fell). The possible impact on Soviet morale of losing Moscow is an open question.

Comment: Yep, assassinate Hitler. He was needed to sweep up the German people into a furore, to start the War. But he was too erratic, too egotistic, to make a good war leader. Assassinate him, say while he is visiting Paris in june 1940. Make it obvious the assassin is British. Now Hitler is no longer a liability, but a Martyr! Operation Sealion gets fast-tracked, Britain is conquered (giving access to british oil in africa and middle-east). With UK gone, Usa might very well have negotiated peace/detente instead. With no UK or US support, Russia is ripe for the plucking.

Answer (score 61):

Seeking a "minimal credible change", I would say that in May/June 1940 the Luftwaffe ignores the rest of the Battle of France and focuses in attacking the British troops evacuating Dunkirk.

Not only the BEF is captured whole, the RAF also suffers a crippling defeat  (fighting over foreign terrain, with little fuel after crossing the channel and without the advantage of radar) and loses most of its planes and pilots, and the Navy also suffers some damage in desperate attempts to break the siege.

After France surrenders (a little later than in original history, due to the respite they got), the UK has no army and the Luftwaffe can guarantee the safety of an invasion fleet against the damaged UK Navy. Realizing that when (not *if*) German units land on British soil the UK will have almost nothing left to negotiate with, recently elected PM Winston Churchill makes an epic speech asking MP to preserve the greatness of the British Empire by signing a peace treaty that gives Germany free reign in Europe and North Africa.

Comment: That's a really good observation. If the Germans had not stood by and let the British escape, things easily could have been different. But I don't agree with your point about the RAF. At a minimum, the disadvantages you mention would apply equally to the Luftwaffe. But I also think the British would have been far more acquainted with northern France than the Germans would be. After all, they had just retreated through it. Plus, the channel is not so wide that it would have a dramatic effect on fuel.

Comment: @Mohair both are reversals of the British advantages during the Battle of Britain. A German pilot parachuting on Dunkirk could fail into German or UK hands, but even if caught by the British he would have been freed when the pocket were captured. Similarly, a British pilot falling inside British lines would have ended as a POW in the end. And the Channel may not be wide, but a UK fighter plane (which had not much range to begin with would have had to cross it twice -and then go from and back the actual air base- severely limiting their fuel for actual combat

Comment: Counter-move: I move 8 battleships and 3 carriers into the channel. The assault on Dunkirk has to endure 15-inch bombardment and the carriers can field enough fighters to keep the Lufwaffle off the battleships for awhile. The channel bases are so close that we can keep 60 fighters in the air almost continuously so long as we can keep refueling the carriers.

Comment: @Joshua the issue with that is that the ships would become sitting ducks for LW (who had way more than 60 airplanes) and U-boots.

Comment: The Luftwaffe **did** savagely attack the British troops at Dunkirk. They simply did not have enough planes to do enough damage. It was the tank forces that did not swoop in on the evacuating forces.

Comment: Almost 200,000 BEF troops were evacuated from Dunkirk to the UK mainland over sea routes of only 70 - 100km. Even with a sustained German land assault on the evacuation (there was already a significant air assault) I think it's likely a good proportion of those troops would still have made it back to the UK, so it's fairly unlikely the BEF would have been "captured whole". In the real timeline the BEF did lose virtually all vehicles, tanks and equipment in the evacuation but the British were still able to recover from this fairly quickly.

Comment: May I recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Hinge-Factor-Stupidity-Changed-History/dp/0340728302) for a fascinating "small moment" that might have prevented the Dunkirk evacuation?

Comment: The Germans didn't possess the necessary landing craft to mount an invasion of Britain. Sea Lion was no more than a paper exercise.  Nice idea though.

Comment: The LW did not have the capability to seriously damage the RN during a short mission.  Even with no RAF cover at all, the LW simply didn't have suitable bombers to really hurt the RN and destroyers would have sunk the invasion fleet.  The RN couldn't station a large fleet in the Channel long term, but they didn't have to.

Comment: With apologies for the huge nitpick, Churchill was the recently *appointed* PM. He was not elected PM in any sense in 1940.

Answer (score 51):

The only thing that would have let the Axis win the war is if they somehow kept the USA out of it. In an alternate reality, this is possible. No super lasers or miracles required.

First, you need someone other than Roosevelt as President. The US Congress was all about neutrality at the time. Many were isolationist. Roosevelt was opposed to this, although he did play along to get his New Deal programs through. But Roosevelt actively supported the British before the USA entered the war.

Second, German U-Boats can't be attacking American shipping. This may not be an issue if the USA is truly neutral, and is staying out of the whole mess. It might be possible for the US to trade with both sides, although I can't see how the British Navy would allow any country to supply Germany. The British were dominant in the Atlantic and in the Mediterranean, so only blockade runners might make it through.

Third, Japan doesn't attack the US. With a more conservative, isolationist President in office, maybe Japan doesn't feel so threatened by the US, and therefore only makes non-threatening moves in Asia. If Japan only attacks the European colonies, then that's a European problem. The USA doesn't enter the war.

If the USA never enters the war, the British are defeated and the war ends. They gave it a really good fight, but Britain cannot do it alone. In the real time line, the USA helped keep Britain afloat before officially entering the war. In the alternate timeline, without that assistance, Britain is done by 1941. With all forces applied to the imminent defeat of Britain, Germany does not invade the Soviet Union in 1941.

After Britain leaves the war, the Germans turn on the Soviet Union, in much more favorable circumstances. By avoiding most of the Russian winter, the Soviets are easily rolled up and done by late 1942. Stalin is deposed. The war is over. Germany takes large chunks of territory and resources from the Soviets. The British, French, Dutch, etc., all have to pay reparations and lose parts of their Empire.

There is "peace" in Europe in 1943. In Asia, it's another story. Now that the allied forces have surrendered to Germany, Japan gets a free hand in Asia and the Pacific. Who is going to stop them? As long as they don't provoke the USA, Japan can do what it wants.

Comment: Entry of the US did not win the war, the US was not a superpower until after the war.  There are a lot of Americans who are a little deluded about this, and as an American biased site, no doubt the truth will be shouted down but Hitler lost the war by attacking Russian during winter.

Comment: Sorry no. With all German forces applied in Britain, USSR surely strikes first, and leaves no chance for Germany to survive.

Comment: @user58697 USSR were in no position to 'strike first'.  Germany won the majority of battles against Russia but was defeated in the war by attrition to the weather.  In hindsight we can say that if Hitler had waited and timed it better he almost certainly would have won over a single summer campaign. Luckily for us he wasn't aware of that and didn't want to take the risk.

Comment: @JamesRyan Soviets were perfectly prepared to strike. The German success in 1941 campaign is mostly due to Soviets not being prepared to defend.

Comment: @user58697 sorry although that is another popular misconception it has been shown by historians to be a complete myth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_offensive_plans_controversy

Comment: @JamesRyan I can't wait to hear the scenario where the USA stays out of the war and the Axis still loses.

Comment: @Mohair I agree with JamesRyan.  The US was not that powerful back then, they had limited standing army before the war, and their distance away from the war (other side of the world and all) made it harder to deploy troops and equipment.  Our biggest advantage was that we hadn't been fighting yet, so we had more men and undamaged industry, both could have helped more if the war had gone on longer.  However, the fact was the Axis was taking on too many enemies already and was not able to sustain it.  We didn't get enough forces in time to be much difference compared to forces already fighting

Comment: Basically, we helped, and the longer the war went the more drastic our assistance would help; once our industry was fully ramped up and everyone else was further crippled by the war.  As it is though, the Axis was already facing a loosing proposition, too many forces to go up against and no way to renew their own forces fast enough.  Our forces  until the end were still tiny relative to what everyone else combined  was contributing anyways

Comment: @JamesRyan, the US was an *industrial* superpower prior to the war.  If you look at production figures for the time period 1939-1945, the United States was turning out as much war materiel as everyone else combined.  Whoever gets that capability on their side pretty much can't lose a sustained war.

Comment: USA had significant economic involvement in the war even before getting actively involved. If isolationist or radical anti-communist USA policies means that the historical Lend-Lease doesn't happen but instead there is some trade in deficit materials with Axis powers, then that definitely would be a big influence on both eastern and western fronts.

Comment: @user58697 The USSR surely would remember Tannenberg, which was the last time they tried to attack Germany in the rear while its attention was elsewhere. It ended badly for the Russians, and it was history that was likely to repeat.

Comment: @Mohair I agree with most of your proposal, but the opening statement that "The *only* thing that would have let the Axis win the war is if they somehow kept the USA out of it" is nonsense. As the other answers here show, there are numerous other possibilities that might have let the Axis powers "win".

Comment: One problem with this: how does Germany force Britain to terms without sinking any American ships delivering supplies to Britain?

Comment: @Mohair Most of the officers didn't even hear about Tannenberg. It was different country who lose that. People in Russia remember that war as civil var not war with Germany.

Comment: @JamesRyan We were not a military super power, but we had unrivaled production capacity, which is what really won the war. We had such a large population by then that it wasn't about how many men we could get to enlist, it was about how the hell are we going to supply them with "boots, beans, bullets, and bandages."

Comment: Philip Roth - The Plot Against America

Comment: This was, of course, the key premise of the Star Trek original series episode *They City on the Edge of Forever* by Harlan Ellison, in which a peace movement started by a woman who "should" have died but is saved by a time-traveller (Dr. McCoy) delays American entry into the war.

Comment: @JamesRyan don't forget the United States was also in the process of building up to be a military superpower. Most of those ships that won the war in the Pacific had been planned prior to Japan attacking Pearl Harbor. While surely the speed at which the USA became a military power changed as a result of WWII, but the [Two Ocean Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-Ocean_Navy_Act) drove a lot of the subsequent military powerhouse that was the USN.

Comment: @enderland The US was only barely coming out of the http://www.britannica.com/event/Great-Depression it was the war and concern leading upto it that brought money back into the US.  It didn't turn up as an economic powerhouse to carry everyone else, in fact instead of supporting europe monitarily the US loaned it to us, effectively charging for it's involvement in the war and a large part of how it was able to become an economic superpower **after the war**.

Comment: Add this, too:  When the Wehrmacht goes into Soviet territory, they don't implement Hitler's racial policies.  Instead of shooting non-Aryans, they instead present themselves as only wanting to overthrow Stalin.

Comment: Jeez you Americans are really brainwashed. The US presense in the WW2 was not critical. The brunt of the war was beared by the Soviet Union: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwKPFT-RioU, without them the Germany would have took all of Europe. US surely gave some weapons and food from the safety of the Ocean and dropped two bombs on the citie of civilians, but that's about it.

Comment: Another variant on this scenario - Japan still attacks the USA but the USA only goes to war against Japan since *Hitler does not declare war on the USA*, leaving the European theatre as a three way between the UK, Germany and the Soviets. If the US focuses all it's resources on defeating Japan, Japan would potentially need to pull back forces from elsewhere in Asia and therefore the British territories in Singapore, Malaysia etc. are retained, along with the defending forces. With more of it's empire intact, Britain stands a much better chance of defeating Germany.

Comment: @JamesRyan Another idiot, beliving the lie of General Winter.

Comment: @dsollen America was a superpotence. Just no militar (Thanks to WWI). If America is no involved, probably Germany wons.

Comment: @JamesRyan US was a economic superpotence just after WWI. (All their competence was wiped out in WWI)

Comment: @Ans The Soviet Union (A demon) really blood a lot, but it was really ineficcient. if the US had no contribuyed London is defeated. And Hitler wins against the URSS.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises ask any historian and they will tell you that it was the soviet Union, and Hitler's idiot choice to open up another front by attacking them, which really spelled the end for the Axis.  Even if the USA never joined the war at all most historians agree the war would have been won by the Allies.  The US contributed sure, and the war ended sooner thanks to our help, but trying to claim we came in and magically saved the day from an otherwise losing war is just revisionist history.

Comment: @dsollen The only "historian" that would have say it is Vladimir Putin.

Answer (score 48):

### Excluding Jews from the Holocaust.

The Jews made up a significant proportion of the German workforce and elite prior to the rise of the Nazi Party. In Weimar Germany, a [significant proportion of elite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Germany#Weimar_years.2C_1919-33) Germans were Jews, and many of them were important scientists. Many Jews fled Germany and settled in other countries, including [Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein#1933:_Emigration_to_the_U.S.), who was later instrumental in [encouraging the Americans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project#Origins) to develop the nuclear bomb in the Manhattan project.

In fact, had the Jews not been targeted for extermination, they could have played significant roles in the war, such as the German atomic bomb project, described in [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/30760/4790).

While the exclusion of Jews would have halved the number of potential scapegoats for the war effort (6 out of 11 million civilians murdered by the Hitler regime were Jews), Hitler still had plenty of targets to choose from. Gypsies (Roma), Communists, Slavs, and other *untermensch* could be potentially targeted. The potential for singling out scapegoats for blame still remains in many parts of the population.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting take on things, actually. Considering how much strategic and technological utility the Allies wound up getting by absorbing the Jewish brain drain, the impact would not have been insignificant. (Why kill off your most highly educated technicians?) This would require a rather deep alteration in the German mindset of the day, though -- Hitler was a product of that environment. He didn't invent ani-Semitism, he merely leveraged and augmented it to propel his own rise (and he really seems to have believed in it himself, but politically that is beside the point).

Comment: Germans (both as a whole and individually) benefitted quite a lot from robbing Jews, also killing (or expelling) them made sure they wouldn’t have the chance to demand back what was theirs later on. Their role as slave workers could mostly be substituted by POWs and civil Slavs on an even larger scale than in OTL (still violating the Geneva Convention). Since some Jews who fought heroically in WW1 received special treatment in the beginning of the holocaust, I could imagine a paradigm shift that made Jews having to **earn citizenship**, e.g. through military service or scientific contribution.

Comment: … That way their role as scapegoat would not go away, but the Reich gets itself some very motivated forces, because life without citizenship in times of war – probably in ghettos like in OTL – would have been a slow death, also less brain drain and no resources wasted on maintaining KZs and transporting people and supplies there. Some nazi state accountant would probably also suggest, maybe successfully, that wealthy Jews could **buy citizenship** for insane amounts of money. Jewish artists, actors, musicians etc. would face work requirements that many of them would refuse to agree to.

Comment: Then again, without the "other within" as a bogeyman, Hitler wouldn't have risen to power.   Given that the Jews are the enemy being used to arouse the rump German population into getting behind a political party espousing aggressive military action beyond its own borders, how could you then succeed in excluding them from the Holocaust?

Comment: @EuanM As mentioned in the answer, other despised ethnic minorities that are less productive to the economy can be targeted. While Jews are the obvious choice in terms of historical oppression, targeting the other minorities would result in far less negative effects.

Comment: The other minorities were much less populous, and much less central to the rise to power of the Nazis.  They were essentially minor addenda.

Comment: e.g. it would have been hard for the Nazi's to make credible claims that Roma bankers were the cause of the people's poverty and the root cause of hyper-inflation.  Where as "*everyone knew*" that the banks were controlled by Jews, so it was easy to have a claim that the Jewish bankers were causing hyper-inflation (and so unemployment) believed.

Comment: @Crissov I would like to add a grain of doubt to that; if you start to offensively discriminate against e.g. Jews, I don’t think that especially the educated people like scientists and artists would agree to the terms of acquiring citizenship; at least not for long. I’d expect them to still flee the country. Also I wonder whether that really works (propaganda-wise and psycologically, when trying to sustain support from the people), building up an "enemy Jew", but excluding a small part of those who work for Nazi Germany or simply have enough money.

Comment: @JonasWielicki It’s a common phenomenon that when people hold strong prejudices against a certain group and finally meet a member thereof who then does not keep up to the superstition, they will attribute this to the individual, therefore not needing to reevaluate the group: “All Jews are bad, but the single one I actually know is an exception!” Earned citizenship – with precedents in ancient Rome etc. – just formalizes this. You’re either born German or proof yourself worthy, might really have worked. Jews throughout history had faced and taken tougher chances for (near) equality or safety.

Comment: @Crissov Did not know that, thanks for the hint. This at least clears up the matter from the side of the remaining population. Still I wonder whether jewish scientists and artists would not have left the country nevertheless. There’s still the discrimination against other fellows, possibly friends, which do not have the means to prove themselves worthy.

Comment: @Crissov yes to what you're saying; moreover, Hitler could still have Jews ostracized on top of all that, and use that in his internal propaganda etc.. How? Just keep the ghetto system without *murdering* the Jews. Maybe create small exclusively Jewish province and deport all Jews there, to live, to work, to contribute to war effort *there*, while resettling the non-Jews from that small area in Germany proper. It would be much more profitable. Choosing mass murder as he did was an enormously evil madness on his part. Without that madness, Germany could have easily won the war.

Answer (score 47):

One of the turning points of WWII was the shift from strategic bombing of the RAF sector bases by the Luftwaffe to the bombing of cities, ordered by Hitler in reprisal for the bombing of German cities by the English.

Had Hitler been a little more rational, had he taken the high moral ground and declared "The Tommies may have bombed our cities, but we will not stoop to their murderous ways" (even though the Germans were secretly exterminating Jews, Gypsies and gays), and carried right on bombing the RAF bases, the RAF would have crumbled under the onslaught, giving the Luftwaffe free reign to go after secondary military targets such as the Royal Navy and army bases in preparation for Operation Sea Lion, the invasion of England.

With the Germans publicly refusing to stoop to the indiscriminate slaughter of civilians in pointless bombing raids on cities, in contrast to the English' attacks on population centres, there would have been diplomatic counter-pressure on the other non-involved nations of the world with regard to becoming involved in this European affair, and if Operation Sea Lion succeeded in the face of a crippled RAF and RN, the US may well have stayed out of the European war entirely.

As a second example of Hitler's improved rationality, he would have held off on his negative propaganda regarding Communism and the invasion of the Soviet Union until after the defeat of Great Britain, and then choosing the appropriate time to strike to avoid the harsh Russian winters.  With a greater number of experienced troops and battle-proven equipment against the Soviet Union's inexperienced troops and unproven equipment, the Germans would have been better placed to press their assault all the way to Moscow.

Comment: I have read that the RAF was days away from defeat because of the bombing of their bases, when a German bomber, lost in the sky over the South of England, jettisoned its bombload at random, but managed to hit the outskirts of London. This provided the justification for the 'retaliatory' bombing of German cities, which led Hitler to target English cities instead of the RAF bases, as above.

Comment: I'm with this answer. However, had the Germans defeated the RAF and then either defeated or hobbled the effectiveness of the RN, they would also have been in a position to negotiate and possibly end the war directly with a large part of Europe under his control (assuming an unlikely level of sanity).

Comment: Would have been difficult (but not impossible) for Hitler to have claimed the high ground. Although they did not initially bomb British cities, they bombed many eastern European cities prior to invasion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_bombing_of_cities#European_theatre

Comment: I think the "hidden" part of this answer is, don't write a book (Mein Kampf) in 1925 that tells everyone who you hate and what your overall plan is, before going to war in 1939.

Comment: The idea that the RAF was days away from defeat is nonsense. 11 Fighter Group was under pressure, but 10 and 12 Fighter Groups, further to the north, were essentially untouched, and pilots from 11 were rotated the other groups for rest during the Battle of Britain. Had the Germans gained air superiority over southeast England, 11 would have withdrawn for rest and replenishment, well out of German fighter range, and then moved back down. And there was no way for the Germans to defeat the Royal Navy.

Answer (score 40):

So many small things, mostly having to do with the Russian campaign.  The simple fact is, if Germany had managed to conquer Russia in 1941, the war is over.  Suddenly they have nearly unlimited oil, food and other natural resources and only one front to face.  For all we like to talk about how the USA's resources would have won out, it was Russia who sucked the life out of the German Army, not the US.

Now certainly they would not have been able to resist without the supplies the US gave them.  But the fact is, they were THERE.  Without a coherent Russian Army to supply - and to be willing to take absolutely appalling casualties and continue - our resources would not have done us much good.

So what would have done it?  Well skipping the Balkan diversion that put off the invasion by something like 6 weeks would have helped.  Germany was in no danger of Yugoslavia invading them.

Or Hitler NOT ordering the Panzers south to trap all those Russians in the Ukraine pocket in late summer.  Without that, they're in Moscow in weeks before the Russian have time to consolidate their defenses or Winter has a chance to set in.

People forget that back then, Moscow was the HUB.  Russian communications were horrendous and they all went through Moscow.  You take Moscow, cut the lines and Stalin is much harder pressed to command his army because he can't even communicate with most of it.  Not to mention the morale blow that would have been.  And Stalin was making a show of actually staying in Moscow.  Odds are they might have capture him.

What Russia needed most of all was time.  Time to get their recently moved factories running.  Time to get the winter troops guarding the Japanese border to the West.  Time to recover from the shock of the German attack.  Time to stiffen the defenses of Moscow.  Time for all the new commanders (who'd replaced the ones Stalin purged) to learn their jobs.  The winter of 1941-1942 gave them that time.

Overall, having an actual military man in charge and not Hitler would have done the trick.  It's often been said that Hitler was the best soldier the Allies had.  So true.  What is amazing is that even with the idiotic decisions the man made and even after years of being worn down, the Germans were able to last until 1945.  Even as late as that year, anytime an allied army met a German army in anything resembling equal strength, the Germans would always do more damage than they took.

Comment: I assume you mean the Yugoslav diversion, The Czechs annexed it before Poland was invaded.  However the spring 41 thaw was exceptionally muddy; while IIRC the Germans had planned on invading sooner the ground wasn't dry enough in much of the USSR to support their tanks until around the actual invasion date.

Comment: One major item you've overlooked is if the Germans hadn't started brutally mistreating civilians in occupied Russia immediately.  Initially there was significant pro-german support (especially in the Baltics/Ukraine) because Stalin was seen as the greater evil; but German actions quickly eliminated any feelings of liberation and replaced them with partisan uprisings.

Comment: You are correct I meant Yugoslavia.  I'm forgetting where the Balkans are.  But Hitler didn't postpone Barbarossa because of wet ground.  He postponed it because of the Balkans.

While mistreatment of civilians certainly did not help the Germans, it also was not any sort of key to victory or loss;  Partisan violence didn't come back to haunt them until it was already too late.  

You take Moscow in 1941 and the rest of Russia become a mop-up operation.  They lacked the coordination, supplies and communication to use their numbers with any effectiveness at that point

Comment: Winning in Russia while fighting on two fronts would have been a *Pyrrhic* victory.  Depleted and exhausted German forces; a USSR with an eviscerated productive capacity; and then the ongoing need to occupy a vast territory against determined resistance fighters.  At which point the Allies roll through Europe to Berlin.  No change in result.

Comment: Germans were fresh in 1941.  Their losses in Russia up until that winter were minimal.  They were making lighting gains, surrounding hundreds of thousands of Russians at a time.  Even with their delays, they were literally within sight of the Kremlin.  The point I am making is that if you take Moscow that winter, then the huge losses they took from late 1942 - 1945 don't happen because that eastern war ends.   Plenty of time to mop up resistance fighters once there is no Russian army to fight (or keeping you from your oil).  And there *was* no second front (in the west) then.  Not until 1943.

Comment: Who's "us" and "our resources" in this answer? That's rather unclear.

Comment: "Us" is the Germans.  "Our Resources" is many things, including the oil that the Germans needed from the Caucasus.  Their only other source of oil at that point was the Ploesti oil fields.  It's also the manpower/equipment resources that the east could have used (to invade Britain, stop the allies, etc) but were unable to due to them all being tied up in a Russian war

Comment: Approximately 80% of German military deaths happened on the Eastern Front and most of those happened after 1941.  Resources would also include former soviet armaments and factories

Comment: Thanks for this answer. USA can be so self centered, while it was the Soviet Soldiers who weared the Germany the  most: https://vimeo.com/128373915. I am a Russian and we did learn about the American supply lines and everything at school, but I don't think they teach Americans about the Soviet input quite as much.

Comment: America always seemed safely away, sending food and weapons, dropping bombs at civilian Japanese cities - all of which helped, but wasn't critical. The Soviets simply didn't have a choice, but to fight, it wasn't some European country that had that option, they knew they would be exterminated if they surrendered, so they would have fought no matter what.

Answer (score 24):

If Nazi Germany had simply declined to declare war on the US after the US declared war on Imperial Japan, the US would have been all-in on the Pacific Theater; the American industrial advantage provided less of a strategic advantage there than in Europe.

With a faster westward sweep across the Pacific, too little time would have elapsed by the time US forces reached the home islands of Japan for the Manhattan Project to have been successfully completed; Operation Downfall would have proceeded resulting in far greater American & Japanese casualties. The appetite of the US to turn its attention to Europe afterward would be questionable at best.

Without the Combined Bomber Offensive, the Nazis could have held up more effectively against the Soviets on the Eastern Front, possibly leading to a stalemate and a separate peace like that at the end of WWI. Fortress Europe could have been prepared more thoroughly in the west, and Operation Overlord, if it was attempted at all, would have been later and smaller with poor prospects.

Comment: Nice. Maybe you could add some demagogue using the "Ships for Bases" Treaty for impeaching Roosevelt "If we had had those ships the Japanese would not have surprised us! And now we have to fight a war without those, and defend pointless bases in the Caribean and North Atlantic!"

Comment: The US would still have continued supplying Britain under Lend-Lease. The legal details of war declarations are not that important if the actual assistance comes through.

Comment: But no USAAF B-17 crews with Norden bombsights crippling German industry; just RAF carpet bombing. Lend-Lease only supplied materiel, not the manpower to leverage it.

Comment: The Germans had been carrying out acts of war on the Eastern seaboard of the USA prior to that.  The USA had been declining to engage in war, despite those provocations, although it had been providing material support to the British.  Once the USA has declared war and begun military action against the Japanese, why would they continue to ignore the German acts of provocation?

Comment: In our actual history, FDR only asked Congress for a Declaration of War against the Empire of Japan despite German provocations.

Comment: @EuanM it would have been difficult to approve "We want revenge from Japan, so we must declare war on Japan. And at the same time we declare war against the more powerful Germany because that will distract us from our goal of revenge" makes not a lot of sense. Note that, while usually combined in the WWII term, Germany and Japan were mostly fighting two separated wars, with just a little collaboration.

Comment: However, they were allied - an attack on one is an attack on all.

Comment: @EuanM Arguably, the attack on one is an attack on all did not apply to a response to an attack by Japan. In any case, Hitler was not noted for adhering to treaties he found inconvenient.

Comment: Germany's sympathizers in the US would have argued for reserving all available materiel for the US war with Japan. Germany could have offered to stop attacking US shipping if the US agreed not to ship munitions to the UK and USSR.

Comment: @Patricia He'd been attempting to provoke war with USA for some time (by harrying shipping along the Eastern seaboard).  It seems he found it convenient.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I normally don't reply to questions that are over 2 years old, figuring that no one is looking at it anymore, but I'm going to make an exception.  The Nazis agreeing to stop attacking US shipping would not have been sufficient -- President Franklin D. Roosevelt was a firm believer in "those that bless Israel shall be blessed" and would not have made peace with the Nazis as long as the Nazis were attacking the Jews (who shouldn't be painted with a broad brush, as I just did).  Some sort of resolution of the Holocaust would have also been necessary, sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 24):

The Allies not having cracked the Axis communication codes.  Updating or replacing the codes the Axis used more often.  Like the Enigma machine and the Japanese naval codes. It seems the Allies had the upper hand after they cracked the codes.

Example: The Battle of Midway. Japan takes heavy losses. "the most stunning and decisive blow in the history of naval warfare." Due to the Allies having cracked the Japanese naval codes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Midway

Example: The success of Ultra.  This has a long list of wins for the Allies. One is the Allies could avoid the u boats, avoiding heavy losses.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra

Comment: The communication codes were cracked several times.  The Enigma code machines were acquired by the Allies several times.  (See the movie "U-571"  It's true that, as the movie says, the Americans acquired a U-boat's Enigma machine.  But the Brits had had one for ages, and it was the Brit's one that was used for the code-breaking that Turing et al engaged in).

Comment: Breaking codes gives you a big advantage, but you still have to go out and win the fight. And, you can't be too successful or the codes will change. It's a tricky thing to manage correctly. And the closer you get to Germany, the less code breaking plays a role, because they don't have to use radios anymore.

Comment: @Mohair If the German naval Enigma was not cracked, U-Boats would have sunk enough British shipping to completely starve them. It is also entirely possible for the Germans to make the Enigma much much harder to crack, through both better stricter operating procedures and better hardware.

Comment: The plausibility that the Brit's could have declined to work with Turing because of his homosexuality should be highlighted here. Then maybe they would have not broken the Enigma. The u-boat war of Germany would have been much much more successful. The stronger u-boat force could also have lead to the allies to not being able to land in the Normandy.

Comment: And not much better hardware.  Adding one more rotor to the working set, and adding a few more rotors to the stock set would have multiplied the time that the bombes took to unscramble the messages.  One of the key factors was that each message started with 3 letters repeated.  (e.g. jkmjkm) This gave two encodings of the same set of letters, with the rotor shifting one step between.  This eliminated a bunch of starting settings for the bombes.  The rotors where easy to make.  Would have been quite practical to use 5 rotors at a time chosen from a set of 8.

Comment: Even having an Enigma coding machine didn't break the code.  You needed to know which rotors to use, and what position, and what the starting position of each rotor was.

Answer (score 24):

Small change you need is Hitler in WWI serving in **logistics**, and realizing importance of logistics and supply for winning wars.

Then, not a single event, but more focus on logistics in each of decision points, more decisive follow-ups of existing events:

1. Understanding the **importance of Gibraltar and Malta** for Britain's logistics, Hitler succeeds persuading Spain to take over Gibraltar and Italy over Malta, to weaken British supply lines in Mediterranean. [Operation Felix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Felix) and [Siege of Malta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Malta_(World_War_II)).

1A. During battle of Dunkirk, focus on total destruction of the British Expeditionary force (300k soldiers). No diverting of Luftwaffe to bombing France. [Dunkirk evacuation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkirk_evacuation) fails. Britain's is weakened, spirit broken. Invasion is not possible (only air raids) but not necessary, and support from USA is weaker (considered a lost cause).

2. Following up more strongly **during Battle of Britain to really won air supremacy** (as @MontyWild correctly noted), realize the importance of radars and destroying them. Switching to bomb London instead of airfields gave RAF time to recover when it was almost broken.
3. After taking over Greece in the spring of 1941, landing up in French part of Lebanon, following up to **occupy British Palestine, Egypt and oil fields in Persian Gulf**. Double whammy for British: losing oil weakens them, and outcome of Battle of El Alamein in 1942 would be different, and would avoid distraction of attacking Russia.
4. In 1941 German paratroopers **occupy Iceland**, significantly improving effectiveness of their submarine warfare and complicating British supply lines from USA.
5. While Goering continues pummeling Britain from air, Rommel wins Battle of Alamein, and attacks British positions in Iran, taking more oil. No more fuel shortages for German tanks, enough left over to supply Japan.
6. **Talking about logistics to Japan.** During attack on Pearl Harbor, continue third (planned!) wave of **attack of fuel reserves in Pearl Harbor**, and on the way back **occupies Midway**, using it as unsinkable aircraft carrier. Basically winning Battle of Midway a year early. Japanese pilots and planes were superior at the beginning of Pacific war – just too many were lost during Battle of Midway.
7. Japan, now understanding the importance of logistics, growing out of strategy of “single decisive battle of battleships” and focusing more on submarine warfare like Germans did, sinking merchant ships bringing fuel reserves and supplies to Pearl Harbor. Possibly even **invading Oahu (which has 10% population of Japanese descent)**. Pacific war is about Hawaii for 2 years. There is no Doolittle raid. Japan will lose that battle, but by that time (1944) Soviet Russia falls to Hitler, and Japan occupied Australia and India.
8. Hitler not declaring war on USA, which was completely irrational.

As a result, USA focuses on Pacific and Japan, and has harder time to get any traction. British fight valiantly but are starved to surrender in 1943. Japan has easier time to take over Southeast Asia and Australia.

Hitler’s attack on Russia is postponed until 1943, and is from both Poland and Iran, taking Baku's oil reserves quickly. With good enough spy network, Stalin in his paranoia executes even more of his military leaders, and when Germany with small help of Japan simultaneously attack in **spring** of 1943, use blitzkrieg tactic in fullest and avoid battles over cities like Stalingrad (surrounding and starving cities instead), Russia crumbles in less than 2 years.

World is divided between Germany, Japan, and USA, which stands alone.

Comment: One question with that: bullet five. There's no significant supply line between Germany and Japan. There's either India or an ocean still under British rule in the way.

Comment: Japan takes over India to join with Germany in Iran. They don't need much contact, just coordinate strategies.

Comment: But India is quite a far stretch for the Japanese forces. Given how the battle of Malaya, the invasion of Burma and all naval warfare in the indian ocean went.

Comment: OK Japan even does not need to take over India. Taking over Australia is enough. Rommel taking over Iran oil fields is enough to weaken UK considerably - if all is left from British empire are colonies in Africa and India, and Canada, war is won.

Comment: @Ghanima The Japanese were [actively fighting the British in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_National_Army). With the British surrendered, high on war exhaustion and low on national morale, it would be even less likely for them to send troops to aid its Indian colonies.

Comment: @Ghanima The British were focussed on critical supply links across the Atlantic.  British troops in the Far East were basically abandoned - they kept fighting, but they had very little support.  The Indian Ocean wasn't anyone's concern.  And if a tanker is carrying a month's supply of fuel, it doesn't really matter that it takes a couple of weeks to get there.

Comment: This is a great comment.   The Germans were so incredibly hampered by Hitler's failure to grasp the basics of logistics.  It's astounding what a fighting force they remained, even with this.

Comment: How would Germany persuaded Spain to join the war?

Comment: It would have been impossible to supply Japan during the war.  Shortly after the US joined it launched a very successful unrestricted sub campaign around Japan and sank 1,200 merchant ships and tankers and 200 warships https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_War#Submarine_warfare  Though it is true logistics is a powerful tool.

Comment: That is exactly my points (6) and (7). With Hawaii occupied by Japan, with the help of 10% local population, Japanese supply lines would be safer.

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear: Spain does not need to join the war at all. All Franco need to do is take over the Gibraltar, which is completely surrounded by Spanish territory. And do it as a "thank-you" for German help in winning the Spanish Civil war. They can do it anytime: Britain is weak, Germany is strong, but the earlier the better.

Comment: @PeterMasiar Taking over Gibraltar is **indeed joining** the war. It is an act of war against Britain and Spain would hafta defend her coasts. Spain would not do that without at least allying with the Axis. And not as a "thank you". Spain had a war debt of around 200M to Germany. Better would be Germany offering to forgive it in exchange for Spain joining the Axis. Then maybe just maybe it would've worked out that way.

Comment: When Hitler wanted Franco to take over Gibraltar, Canaris (chief of German spy agency, and part of clandestine Nazi oposition) persuaded him not to. [Operation Felix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Felix). Also, it is unlikely that Britain could mount any significant retaliation on Spain for taking Gibraltar while under attack by Germany.

Comment: Based on any reasonable analysis off technology, logistics, military capacity and the then current geopolitical situation Points No.s (2) (3) (4) (6) (7) & 9*) are non starters. Thees not enough space to respond in detail but  - (2). they tried but the radar system had multiple back-ups and redundancies available and are point targets anyway - very hard to knock out for long.  (3) required the Italian Navy to defeat the British navy. (4) Unless they swim there the Germans aren't getting to Iceland in force. (6)  Japan cant win against the US no matter what it does, only delay the inevitable.

Comment: 7) See point 6 above. Sink every ship in the US Pacific Fleet, occupy Pear Harbor it doesn't matter. During WW2 the US reproduced their entire pre-war fleet Pacific fleet tonnage plus more! in less than 4 years. Example?  During the war the US produced almost 350 destroyers. Japan? less than 40. (8) Doesn't matter, following Pearl Harbor the US would have entered the war on the allied side anyway. The attack there pushed the momentum for active participation (vs isolationism) across the line.

Answer (score 22):

The Italians could have discovered oil in their Libyan colony before WWII.  Those huge oil reserves weren't actually exploited until the 1950s, but if they were producing during WWII the axis would be relieved of some of their desperate need for oil.

Comment: But then the British beat the Italians in Africa (like they did in real life) and Hitler extends his forces farther to protect them. This ends in Hitler still invading the USSR, Japan still hitting Pearl Harbor. Hitler now faces the two most capable nations on Earth capable of combatting him AT THE SAME TIME. [Operation Torch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Torch) squeezes the Axis from the West. British forces from Egypt supplemented by Indian conscripts push Germany from the East, taking the Libyan oil fields, [Operation Overlord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Overlord)

Comment: takes France. Oil would only prolong the war, not turn it in favor of Germany.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan: Hitler neglected the African front historically, but if it was the fascists' oil source he probably would have invested more in that front, enough to defend it against the relatively small British army at least.

Comment: ...and Rommel would not have run low on  fuel...also, Italy might have industrialized more, so would have been a more effective ally.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades  I never said he wouldn't defend it better, but Hitler and his allies had only so many men and only so much material, since his invasions damaged the industrial capacity of the nations he conquered. With > 4 million Russian soldiers pressing in the east and [many millions](http://www.historyshotsinfoart.com/USArmy/backstory.cfm) of Americans preparing for an invasion in the west, Hitler would still be screwed. Germany deployed [3 million men](http://spartacus-educational.com/2WWgermanA.htm) against Russia I will assume it had maybe 2 - 4 million men for other fronts...

Comment: @JonofAllTrades This would still leave them over stretched, and even if American invasions failed a couple of times, Germany's manpower would eventually be worn down to impossible odds. Their only chances would become a good peace deal that the allies did not intend to give them, or wearing the allies population down, which Germany had failed miserably at in the Battle of Britain and the American population was pissed from Pearl Harbor. American recruiting facilities supposedly had to turn back recruits until supplies could be produced for their training and deployment.

Comment: The British navy could have easily blocked most of the fuel from getting across the Mediterranean Sea. Then Hitler would have to chose between trying to choke Britain and protect his Africa oil. Knowing him, he would order his limited navy to combat the British in both the Atlantic and Mediterranean resulting in disaster in both.

Answer (score 19):

## The Weather.

This is all kind of 'supernatural' but in coincidence only:

**Eastern Front:** It's [commonly understood](https://www.quora.com/Was-weather-what-ultimately-saved-the-USSR-from-defeat-in-World-War-2) that the cold, wet, harsh winter in Russia greatly hampered the German advance.  Have an unusually warm winter in '41, '42, and '43, and it is possible if not probable that this would help to crush Russia's western troops.  It was an absolute contributing factor to Germany's losses there.

**German Bombings:** Rain and snowstorms erupting during bombing raids prevents the allies for even being able to target industrial complexes.  Rain distributes evenly to assist in putting out the fires that raged under allied bombing.

**Atomic Bombs:** The original target for both atomic bombs was [meant to be over Kohura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokura#World_War_II), but due to weather, they had to move first to Hiroshima, then to Nagasaki (twice lucky for Kohura).  Imagine if weather thwarted all nearby Japanese targets, preventing the United States to use the bombs - US bombers had limited range over Japan's southern quarter, so bad weather over the general quarter would have delayed any bombing of this type for a long time.

**Dust Bowl:** More waves of drought from the dust bowl over the United States might have forced more civil works to be undertaken, as well as reluctance to support pre-war allied efforts (food), and entrance into the war.

**Pearl Harbor:** Weather patterns that prevent the Japanese carriers and bombers from approaching American territory might have kept the Japanese from "kicking the sleeping bear," long enough for the other factors to encourage Japan to refocus on East China and allow America to look inward.

**Naval Warfare:** Weather is always a factor on the outcome and procedure of naval warfare and amphibious invasion. A series of 'unfortunate' weather events could occur in favor of Axis victory.

All of these are very, very coincidental, but then was the succession of unusually cold and wet Russian winters a coincidence, or the fact that Kohura avoided the bomb twice by weather?

Also, can I be cheeky and say "Yellowstone Super-volcano Event"?

Comment: In fact the main issue in the Eastern Front was not winter, but autumn rains that converted everything in mud (rasputitsa) as there were very few roads (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhstOECIm_0). Winter solidified the mud and allowed for new operations. A different issue was that the German were overconfident that war would be over before winter set so they did not supply adequate winter materiel to their troops.

Comment: @SJuan76 - but it was also unusually cold for three years in a row.  If it had been sunny and (relatively) warm, the outcome most certainly would have been different.

Comment: Can I ask what the -1 was for?  I hope it wasn't the Yellowstone comment :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I am skeptical that a specific weather event could have turned the tide, so to speak. Is there a specific battle where you think events could have led to an Axis victory, given specific weather?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades - my "tightly interconnected events" are listed (bombings, military advances, food security in the US, etc.); as the OP said, "It doesn't have to guarantee an Axis victory, but it has to significantly increase its probability"

Comment: @SJuan76 the intereptation that I read was not so much "expected the war to be over" but rather "having studied Napoleonic times, Hitler knew that fighting in Russia in the winter would be disastrous and so refused to jinx himself with a winter campaign and provide every motivation for the troops to want it to be done before winter by not providing supplies." - how accurate that is, I'm not certain though. Not so much overconfidence but rather "it *must* get done before winter."

Comment: The Winter of 1947 would have finished the war in Europe early by mass starvation had it come earlier. But I'm not sure whether the UK would have surrendered before the German people turned on their leaders. The UK had rationing and a "land army" in place,  Germany did not.

Comment: @nigel222 - Agreed.  Also, Western Europe and particularly the UK have a geographic advantage to extreme cold events such as that, being moderated just a bit by the ocean.  So their 'homelands' would have a bit more advantage to providing logistical help.

Comment: This is 1 of the **most plausible** alternate histories posted here, but sadly it's unlikely to be used because it's not very enthralling. In alternate history fiction, people wanna read about conspiracies, realizations, other plotting towards victory. Weather is just Deus ex Machina in the literary world. It's too bad cuz even modern warfare can be impossible during a bad storm. The weather is not given its due appreciation. An unusually warm winter is just as likely as an unusually cold winter, from a probability standpoint.

Comment: However, I still hafta agree with @SJuan76 that the rasputitsa was a bigger factor than winter. I would choose a non-Yugoslavia, non-Balkan course, to let Barborossa start earlier than June 22, combined with some of the weather stuff you listed. Just keep in mind none of it will matter once the A-Bomb is invented, unless America is unwilling to use it or it doesn't get invented at all.

Answer (score 16):

**The Polish Cipher Bureau never cracks the German Enigma cipher code** (or - the Polish fail to share the information on cracking the cypher with British and French intelligence before the outbreak of war and the information is lost with the fall of Poland).

The other powers such as the British and French had no success in cracking Enigma and without the intelligence provided by the British "Ultra" program (that continued the work of the Poles) at Bletchley Park the entire Allied war effort in Europe would have been seriously undermined. Eisenhower described the intelligence originating from Bletchley Park and the Enigma decryption as having been "of priceless value to me. It has simplified my task as a commander enormously" and as a "decisive contribution to the Allied war effort".

Comment: Eisenhower is very much secondary.  Not to detract from the invasion of Europe, but the Allies didn't launch the invasion until they were certain the Germans couldn't stop them.  Cracking Enigma was key to intercepting U-boats though, and without that they couldn't have resupplied Britain or got US and Canadian troops across the Atlantic.

Comment: Read up on Willi Korn and his invention of the "reflector" in the Enigma. It turned out to be the main cryptological weakness of the machine. Had Korn realized that, it would have been *much* harder to break it.

Answer (score 15):

One decimal point .
The Nazi nuclear project is set back many years because 1 scientist put the decimal in the wrong place when measuring the neutron cross section of carbon.  The axis try to use very rare heavy water for early experiments where the allies use cheap graphite, and send commando raids to destroy every heavy water plant in Europe.

With the speed up that this gives the axis nuclear program then could have a Nuclear warhead in time for Dday or perhaps Stalingrad.

Comment: That would have been way too late in the war to make a difference, though. It would have been obvious that the nuke shot was a one-off capability and that they didn't have any more left (if they used it at Stalingrad, why not on D-Day or vice-versa, why didn't they halt the Americans in North Africa with another one, etc.). This would have *dramatically* accelerated the Allies operational pace and radically altered their acceptable risk calculation (and remember, "acceptable risk" back then wasn't what it is today). The Bomb in 1935, though...

Comment: DDay and Stalingrad were a year and a half apart they could have had a nuke for each.  Its true that the axis might still lose the war but  breaking Stalingrad or Kursk in the axis favor would have extended the war by a year or two, or forced the soviets to and armistice at a key moment.  9/10 of the German army was deployed on the eastern front having them free to attack else where would have been a problem.

Comment: I think it is profoundly optimistic to assume that Germany, considering its logistical situation, could have produced a second bomb, guaranteed to work, with a reliable delivery system, within 18 months. Just being able to blow a test munition is a *very* different thing from being able to ruggedize one sufficiently for deployment. Of course we *are* worldbuilding here -- so I submit that this is a problem that has to be explained and managed by whatever the world alteration is in-universe (discovery of high-yield uranium deposits within Germany might help, for example).

Comment: Actually, didn't something like this actually happen? The German scientists didn't account for the boron content in the graphite and got different results using it as a moderator? There's a mention of it on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Pile-1  So, that could be a single small change (realizing the graphite was impure) with far-reaching consequences.

Answer (score 14):

There are a number of good possibilities.  Here's just one:

Hitler succeeds in convincing Japan to make the Soviet Union its primary focus.  Especially if this happens early, ideally prior to and coordinated with operation barbarosa.  If Japan focused on attacking the U.S.S.R. from the east while Germany attacked from the west, they could have squeezed the Soviets and defeated them.  And another bonus would be Japan, by focusing on the U.S.S.R., would not have attacked the U.S.A., which was a fatal mistake no matter how you slice it.  The U.S. would likely never get in the war, the U.S.S.R. would be eliminated, Britain would have stood alone and would have pretty much had to give up.

Comment: The Japanese Army was crushed by the Soviets at Nomonhan in 1939.  The lack of decent artillery and armor would make it impossible for the Japanese to "squeeze" anything.  This distraction would only have a minor effect on the East Front versus Germany.

Comment: @Oldcat The Japanese attacked the Soviets far too early. Had they timed it simultaneously with Operation Barbarossa instead of provoking the Americans, it would be far harder for the Soviets to respond with sufficient force.

Comment: 18 divisions from the far east were a major part of the soviet counterstrike at Moscow in December '41. It's hard to tell if their absence (if needed against Japanese forces) would have tipped the tide but it's an option discussable in the frame of this question.

Comment: It isn't the timing. It was that the quality of military hardware the Japanese had was totally insufficient to deal with the Soviets - that same army that had trouble with the Finns that same winter.  The Soviets could have just ignored them, as there's nothing worth taking in the Far East.  And as soon as they had breathing room, the Japanese would be crushed in an open field campaign.

Comment: Thank you, Ghanima, that is part of what I was talking about, I neglected to mention it specifically. I think it *does* make a difference at Moscow, and that's a big deal. I agree that the best Soviet move at that point would be to ignore the Japanese, but it's not so clear to me that they would have actually done that. If the Japanese fighting the Soviets-- even if Oldcat is right (he probably is) and they wouldn't be powerful enough to make any inroads on them-- if it weakens their ability to resist the Germans in the west it still makes a difference.  A two-front war is never an easy thing.

Comment: Those far East troops were put in *after* the offensive was stopped.  So they weren't needed to keep Moscow from falling (and Moscow falling would not have ended the war regardless).  So the best case for the Germans is a slightly less powerful **counteroffensive** in Winter 41.  But the Soviets rebounded all along the line that winter, not just where those Far East troops were inserted.

Comment: interesting note - the site http://www.operationbarbarossa.net/ , these 14 divisions of Siberians were sent to the Leningrad front for the most part, not even to the Moscow area. http://www.operationbarbarossa.net/the-siberian-divisions-and-the-battle-for-moscow-in-1941-42/

Comment: This works in theory but only if you solve 2 problems: Japan performed very poorly against Russia in the Battle of Khalkin Gol (1939). Japan needed oil, which is why they were moving towards Indonesia. Khalkin Gol was a relatively small battle compared to what would be needed for a massive Siberian attack. Best they could hope for is a raid to temporarily cut off the Trans-Siberian Railway, then bring in a battleship to assault Vladivostok. All of this is temporary distraction, but with extraordinary good timing, might stop Siberian Division Transfer long enough.

Answer (score 12):

The key to the Allied victory in WWII is logistics and production. The United States, for example, produced something like 8 X the annual steel production of Imperial Japan at the start of the war, so the Japanese simply had no chance of winning in the Pacific once the United States was engaged. The British Empire was similarly capable of lopsided production compared to the Axis powers, and Churchill implicitly acknowledged this in his "We will fight on the beaches" speech:

> Even though large tracts of Europe and many old and famous States have fallen or may fall into the grip of the Gestapo and all the odious apparatus of Nazi rule, we shall not flag or fail. We shall go on to the end. We shall fight in France, we shall fight on the seas and oceans, we shall fight with growing confidence and growing strength in the air, we shall defend our island, whatever the cost may be. We shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets, we shall fight in the hills; we shall never surrender, and if, which I do not for a moment believe, **this island or a large part of it were subjugated and starving, then our Empire beyond the seas, armed and guarded by the British Fleet, would carry on the struggle,** until, in God's good time, the New World, with all its power and might, steps forth to the rescue and the liberation of the old.

The British Empire, fighting alone, probably had enough manpower and industry to win WW II by 1948 (Consider that Canada, a tiny Dominion at the time, was capable of putting a million men under arms, and fielded the world's third largest navy by 1945, and Canada was only one part of the Empire).

So the only way for the Axis powers to win is *not* to provoke war with all the Great Powers, but rather nibble around the edges and then take them one at a time.

Defeating the Soviet Union is probably the first step. The USSR was an odious nation and outside of the normal international system (both by choice and the design of the Liberal *and* Imperial powers of the age), and by careful use of diplomacy to make the Russians even more isolated (the 1939 "Winter War" with Finland might have been played that way), along with encouraging the Japanese to try to pin the Russian forces in Siberia could have crippled Russia and knocked it out of the war. Germany and Japan dismember the USSR and feed on the resources, while carefully keeping clear of the British Empire and American interests.

After a pause of perhaps 5-10 years, it could become time to use aggressive diplomacy to sow dissent among the various member states of the British Empire. Imperial Forces become overstretched trying to police the various rebellions across the globe, and Churchill is long retired, leaving the British with something of a leadership vacuum. Germany and Japan support "revolutionary forces" and welcome defecting members of the Empire into the New Order and the Co Prosperity Sphere, gradually dismembering British power. Ironically, the Americans would probably be very happy to see this process, and if not encouraging it directly, they would make no diplomatic steps to stop it either.

America itself would be the hardest nut to crack, being a continental and oceanic power in its own right. Even with the resources of Asia and the British Empire now under Axis control, America has far more potential power because it's free market economy allows it to use resources most efficiently and develop new products and industry at unexpected times, complicating axis power. If you have any doubts, research the true story of the Axis economy during WW II. Most German aircraft were still using engines designed in 1933 at the end of the war, and obstruction by petty bureaucrats in the ship building industry long delayed the introduction of modular production of the Type XXI U Boats, to name a few. Tank production always lagged far behind the allies, and although Panther and Tiger tanks may have been far better than the opposition, they were essentially hand crafted, while Shermans and T-34's were churned out on assembly lines.

The best way to win against America again is through the indirect approach, gradually subverting South America into getting Fascist regimes (not to difficult, if you look at OTL) and gradually choking off overseas trade. America is never conquered directly, but simply declines into irrelevancy and accepts the domination of the New Order and Imperial Japan in their own spheres.

Comment: A dramatic change to the outcome may have resulted had Japan metabolized its early gains prior to the American entry to the war. The discussion has been so Germany + A-bomb centric I had forgotten of this. Had Japan encountered a rough spot (instead of invincible-seeming night naval victories and a clean sweep on land straight to SE Asia) that made them consolidate and recognize their indigestion Washington's split burden would have been far more difficult to balance. Japan, after all, is the inventor of the naval uber-weapon without having had realized it: the carrier-launched aerial torpedo.

Comment: I agree with much of this but have to disagree about Britain.  There is no way they could have come close to winning the war fighting alone.  Even with all of the support of the United States plus the Russians (27 million dead, remember) Britain was a spent force by 1945.  Their numbers began to decrease in 1944 actually.  You take away all of the American arms/supplies shipments, air support, troops from Normandy onwards (and in Africa, Italy) plus the simple fact that the vast majority of Germans dying were doing so in the east... Britain would not have lasted past 1943 all by themselves.

Comment: The Axis had no reasonable means of preventing the Dominions or colonies from producing men and equipment for the war, and while England was a spent force by the end, Canada, Australia, South Africa and India certainly were not. This is where I believe the British Empire could have won on its own, much more slowly and at a greater cost, to be sure.

Comment: Canada and Australia were not colonies.  They were sovereign countries.

Comment: A Dominion is a semi-independent country within the Empire; until the late 1930's, Canada's laws still needed to go through the British House of Lords for final ratification, and the Canadian Constitution wasn't "repatriated" until 1982.

Comment: The Soviets had lost a lot of their international pariah status starting in the mid-'20s, after they backed off of the idea of an international communist revolution and developed the idea of "Socialism in One Country".  Perhaps if Trotsky had won out over Stalin, the USSR would have stuck with the idea of permanent revolution and would have stayed a pariah for longer.

Comment: @Thucydides Canada was actually very reluctant to enter the war at all. I first learned of this when reading about the Alaskan Highway, which needed Canadian permission to build and they were afraid it might make Japan declare war on them. I think Canada would have to be drafted rather forcefully. Theoretically, India has plenty of manpower, but again, you have to draft and train them which takes quite a while and has costs all its own.

Comment: As a Canadian, I can safely tell you that the *Liberal Government* of Canada was reluctant to enter the war, and thought the Commonwealth Air Training Plan (using Canada's vast spaces to allow Commonwealth air forces to train) might be the limit of participation. Canadians thought otherwise, and the Liberals certainly were feeling pressure both internally and externally. By the end of the War, Canada had over a million men under arms, the world's third largest navy, a formidable air force and a fully mobilized industrial base.

Answer (score 11):

Churchill refuses to become Prime Minister in the meeting on 10 May 1940; instead Halifax succeeds Neville Chamberlain. Britain soon makes peace with Germany (no "We shall never surrender").

This is the [Point of divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_divergence) in the book [Dominion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion_%28Sansom_novel%29) by [C. J. Sansom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._J._Sansom).

Comment: I can't imagine Churchill refusing. That goes completely against his nature. Perhaps a more realistic scenario is that he is killed in a car/plane/ship accident. Or by an assassin. Either way, that is an interesting suggestion.

Comment: Replaced by Reptilians maybe?

Comment: There is no way that Churchill refuses.  He'd been manoeuvering for it for decades, and got much more active about it once the war began.  Churchill dying prior to the time the offer is made is possible, though.

Comment: Churchill was knocked down and nearly killed by a motorcar in New York City in 1931. This may be too long before the war to qualify for our discussion, but removing Churchill from this timeline surely has a significant effect on the Battle of Britain.

BTW Hitler was also nearly in a fatal auto accident in that same year, as baron John Scott-Ellis barely avoided mowing him down in Munich with his brand new little red Fiat.

Comment: Does this really change the outcome? The UK out of the war leads to a more concentrated force by the Axis in the east (not divided in protecting the French coast or invading Egypt), but doesn't really affect Axis productivity (the Germans could have had vastly greater productivity than they did before Barbarossa, but were not really motivated to do so until they started losing). Nah, no Churchill means no US in Europe. Would the Axis have won against the USSR? Possibly... but... if not, it means an entirely Red post-war Europe.

Comment: @A. I. Breveleri  I read the same thing about Churchill's near-miss (in a book of counter-factuals by historians), except that it was a taxi.

Answer (score 10):

Answers that suggest that Nazi Germany not attack the USSR are technically correct, insofar that Germany would not be beaten by the rump of the Allies after the Fall of France, but this ignores the fact that conquest of the USSR had always been a primary motive of Hitler - much moreso than any concerns in the West. While there were certain failings in the invasion of the USSR; such as the lack of preparation for winter, the division of resources in multiple theatres (such as Africa), Hitler's refusal to allow retreat at a couple of important junctures, etc., the *single* greatest failing of the Axis was not to exploit the great antipathy among subjugated nations of the USSR towards the Kremlin.

By instigating the [Hunger Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunger_Plan) the Axis made an enemy of nations such as the Ukraine and Baltic states. The little that they gained in raw resources was vastly outweighed by the logistical cost wrought by partisan groups in a country with notoriously poor infrastructure: never mind the vast resource of people that could have been leveraged in a war against the USSR. In a theatre where swift victory was a requirement, the implementation of the Hunger Plan was probably the single greatest strategic blunder by the Axis in the war.

Comment: Don't forget it takes time and resources to **train** the Ukrainains, Belorussians, etc, or they won't be much good in battle at all. There are also language barriers to overcome and I'm not sure if Germany had enough translators to train/employ them all in reasonable time. Another idea is to use them for simpler labor like trainyards and maybe factories. (German factory foremen were always complaining that the Wermacht drafted too many good men from them.) But your main point still applies. Hitler thought Russia would fall very soon, so to hell with the *Untermenschen*.

Answer (score 9):

Not yet mentioned:
If Edward VIII had taken Wallis Simpson as his mistress and not his wife, he would not have abdicated. 
As he was a supporter of Germany's policy, the British Government would not have been able to go to war and instead would have sought diplomatic solutions with the third reich.

Also IMHO if Hitler had been assassinated (e.g. Valkyrie) fresh leaders might have pushed into stabilizing the reich to pre war borders (as per the Munich agreements) which might have been acceptable to the Allies.

Comment: The Royal Prerogative lies with the Prime Minister. It is not the Monarch who decides about declarations of war.  The Monarch has served at the pleasure of the citizenry since the Restoration.

Answer (score 9):

In late autumn 1941, German troops were at the gates of Moscow. And this is where they suffered their first serious defeat: the failure of the Moscow offensive was both a psychological blow and an end to any hopes of a successful *blitzkrieg* in the East.

This first Soviet victory was possible in large part due to troops (experienced, winter-equipped troops) moved to Moscow's defense from the Far East, to the astonishment of many German commanders who believed that the enemy is on the verge of collapse with no reserves left. And this was made possible in large part by the efforts of Richard Sorge, the famous Soviet spy in Tokyo who informed Moscow that the Japanese have no plans to attack the Soviet Union anytime soon, being preoccupied with plans in the Pacific instead. And this time, Stalin chose to believe Sorge (reportedly, he ridiculed Sorge earlier the same year, when Sorge provided intelligence about the imminent German attack, i.e., Barbarossa).

This leads me to believe that if either Germany managed to persuade Japan not to pursue any plans in the Pacific until the Soviet Union is defeated, or better yet, if they simply caught Sorge (or if Sorge was simply killed in an accident) before he had a chance to transmit this critical intelligence to Moscow, the Germans might have been able to capture the Soviet capital. And that may very well have led to the collapse of Stalin's regime and a completely different (likely, far more tragic) outcome for Europe and the world.

Comment: Japan had already been waging war against China for *years*, and desperately *needed* the resources the US / UK / NL embargo suddenly denied them. Japan only had the choice of effectively cancelling their expansion in SE Asia, retreating to their island and mope, or antagonizing the US -- which they did by preemptive strike a.k.a. Pearl Harbor. I don't see how capturing Sorge could have changed that.

Comment: Capturing Sorge could have prevented Stalin from knowing about Japan's plans in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to @MartinSchröder's answer.

**What if Churchill was not British Prime Minister?**

He was struck by a car in 1931 by [Edward F. Cantasano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_F._Cantasano).

If it had been a fatal accident, a very different Britain would have faced Germany.

Answer (score 7):

## Allies were receptive to the idea of peace

There is a fair bit of evidence that Hitler was open to peaceful resolutions, but the allies were either not interested or did not trust Hitler's promises.  A story where the alies "lose" could certainly go in two different directions:

- Conflict with the allies ends sooner, allowing Germany to focus on Russia sooner (possibly even with the assistance of the Allies)
- Hitler goes back on his promises and does even more dastardly deeds in the name of world domination when everyone's guard is down

### British government considers negotating peace in 1940

> The argument revolves around the confusing and inconclusive records of deliberations in Churchill's cabinet in May and June 1940 over whether Britain should discuss peace terms with Germany, records over which historians have argued for the 30 years that they have been available.
>
> There is no disagreement that the cabinet debated whether Britain should sound out Hitler on what kind of peace terms he might offer. Nor is there any doubt that Churchill made comments that do not entirely support his image as the stalwart hero, pursuing the goal of ''victory at all costs'' and refusing even to contemplate negotiations with Berlin. He is recorded as declaring, for example, that ''if we could get out of this jam by giving up Malta and Gibraltar and some African colonies,'' he would ''jump at it,'' although he didn't see any such prospect. He also declared that he was prepared to accept ''peace on terms of the restoration of German colonies and the overlordship of Central Europe,'' which presumably included continued occupation of Czechoslovakia and western Poland, although, again, he said that such an offer was ''most unlikely.''

http://www.nytimes.com/2000/11/25/arts/rethinking-negotiation-with-hitler.html?pagewanted=all

### Rudolf Hess offers peace deal with Britain in 1941

> The Nazis attempted to broker a peace offering with Britain - if they were allowed a free path to attack the USSR, a new book has revealed.
>
> Rudolf Hess's flight to Britain during World War Two to sign a peace deal ordered by Adolf Hitler has long been recorded as a bizarre one man mission to try and reconcile warring West Europe and the Nazis.
>
> But the high-ranking Nazi was actually carrying out orders from the Fuhrer when he flew to Messerschmitt to Scotland in May 1941.
>
> But despite the offer, Churchill's morals were not swayed by the offer.
>
> He refused to allow the Third Reich a clear path to attack the Eastern Front - because he did not trust Hitler's promises and it would have jeopardised his efforts to involve the U.S in the raging war, Mr Padfield says.

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2433733/How-Nazis-offered-peace-treaty-World-War-II-meant-selling-Russians.html#ixzz3tMBkzFMI

Answer (score 7):

*We don't know*. And a war hinges on many factors, not just one. But there are definitely three that are on my mind; perhaps a *single* one would suffice, but since only one of them is a "large scale" change, the other two could very easily have happened as well. So, from biggest to smallest (in "difficulty to attain"):

---

**Military: Greece.**

Italy's blunder in Greece (or basically, wherever they set foot in WWII, but let's focus on Greece...) meant that Germany had to divert forces, mostly from Africa, where the campaign (which originated in another, earlier blunder by Italy) was at a crucial stage, with the Commonwealth forces on the brink of defeat.

Of course we don't *know* what *would* have happened if Italy had stayed out of Greece, *or* managed a decisive victory (possibly with *planned* German help), but I (and [Ian Kershaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Kershaw) in *"Fateful Choices: Ten Decisions That Changed the World, 1940–1941"*) consider it possible that the Africa Corps *could* have taken Egypt from the Commonwealth.

*What would that have meant?*

- **The Suez channel**. Taking that away would have been a *huge* strategic blow for Britain, basically demolishing their presence in the eastern Mediterranean. Any shipping from Britain to the asian theater and back -- military as well as commercial -- would have had to go the long way around.
- **Yugoslavia.** *Without* Greece humiliating Italian forces right next door, Yugoslavia might well have joined the Axis for good.
- **Crete.** The whole point of this operation was to better support the Africa campaign. With Egypt and the Suez taken, Germany could have taken, besieged, or even ignored Crete without taking those losses that blunted both the German paratrooper force *and* air transport capabilities for the rest of the war.
- **Italian Navy.** With the command of the (eastern, at least) Mediterranean, I doubt the [Battle of Taranto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Taranto) would have taken place quite that way, leaving the Italian Navy intact as a strategic force.
- **Italy remains in the Axis.**
- **Theater Denial.** No bombing of the Ploiești oil fields, for one. And but with Egypt and the Suez channel lost, it is even conceivable that pressure could have been applied to Gibraltar, *completely* securing the Mediterranean for the Axis and denying the Allies access to the southern coasts of Europe (no invasion of Sicily 1943).
- **No delay to Operation Barbarossa.**

Which brings us to the next point:

---

**Nature: Weather.**

The spring muds of 1941 were quite late. Let's have weather be a *bit* more favourable, and with the distraction of Greece and Yugoslavia not happening, or being resolved much earlier, the Axis forces might have had those few more weeks in their favour so the attack would not freeze solid at the gates of Moscow later that year. With Moscow taken away, the railroad backbone of Russia being broken, and mostly open fields all the way to the Volga river...

Now let's look at the last, easiest to attain, but probably the most important of them all:

---

**Intelligence: Not having your ciphers broken.**

Willi Korn not "inventing" the reflector would very likely have been sufficient to protect the Enigma. There are some other issues, but the reflector alone would probably have been enough.

Not being all German precision on the *contents* of messages would also have helped, as it would have avoided known-plaintext attacks.

And whoever the man was who repeated a 4000-character Lorenz cipher transmission without changing the key settings in August 1941, *that* the German war effort could have done without as well.

Either one would have been *dead* easy, and would have taken away the biggest advantage the Allies ever had in the war: They could read Germany's cipher, basically at will.

Comment: Pouring through the other answers, allow me to hijack [a link posted by @AndyD273](http://www.militaryhistoryonline.com/wwii/articles/invadingrussia.aspx). Note how my "quick victory in Greece" variant basically combines *both* options presented in that paper: Strengthening the position in the Mediterranean *and* attacking Russia earlier and with more force.

Comment: My answer was going to be **"Have Mussolini bring a translator"**, which basically becomes your answer by the end.

Comment: @vulpineblazeyt: That's actually interesting. Are you referring to a specific event, or just generally to the Duce and the Führer not really being on the same page?

Comment: In general; although iirc from history class, there was a specific in-person meeting about the campaign against Greece that, if Mussolini had full understanding of, would not have ordered his troops to attack when he did. 

In general, Italy worked against the Axis, rather than for it, in the military sense.

Answer (score 6):

The Germans never attack the Russians and are allied with them throughout the war.  (Yeah I know this answer apparently isn't allowed, but why not?).   Hitler's biggest mistake was opening up the second front.  In a more peaceful alternative, Eastern Europe is divided between Germany and Russia.  Russia expands through Norway, Sweden, Finland, Iceland, and Greenland towards the US & Canada.  Germany progresses through the UK towards the US.  Japan only enters the war after the fall of the UK, pressuring the US on two fronts after Europe is secured.

Also, Mexico decides to join the Axis and invades the Southern states ;).

Comment: Germany never had enough air and sea power to successfully invade England Russia doesn't have much to add why would they suddenly be able to take Germany

Comment: Why is a Russian-German alliance not allowed?  Or even just neutrality?
The lack of that front against Germany, combined with Russian resources now being available to Germany, would completely change the European situation.

Comment: But the whole point was to clear the east to make Lebensraum. Without invading Russia the whole war makes no sense (well, to those who started it).

Answer (score 6):

Speed wins battles, but sieges win wars.

Blitzkrieg as a war manoeuvre was never going to create an empire. If the Nazis had realised this they would have followed their lightning conquests with extended occupation and stabilisation of the invaded territories. The stretching of the Eastern front to the USSR was ill-advised too. Hitler should have first consolidated his rule of Eastern Europe for maybe five years before advancing to Moscow.

The one pivotal decision that sealed Germany's fate though was bombing England. This leads to the replacement of [Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville_Chamberlain) with Churchill,  whose intention from the start was to defeat the Nazis and bait the USA into joining the war.

So if Hitler had only expanded to Eastern Europe and ignored Russia maybe Deutsch would be Europe's first language.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I found some info that suggests that attacking Russia may not have been a bad idea, just badly executed. In case you are interested: http://www.militaryhistoryonline.com/wwii/articles/invadingrussia.aspx

Comment: @AndyD273 interesting reading. Hadn't examined the Russian invasion from that angle  before

Answer (score 6):

### Death of Alan Turing

The Allies' ability to decrypt Axis communications played a major part in the ultimate Axis defeat.

### Defeat at Dunkirk

The evacuation of Dunkirk allowed the British army to retreat and regroup. If the fleet of small ships had been destroyed by Axis gunships, England would have been a sitting duck.

### Pearl Harbour never happened

The Americans joined the war following the Japanese attack on Pearl Harbour. Without the huge industrial might of America, the Allies would likely not have won the war.

Comment: Read up on Willi Korn and his invention of the "reflector" in the Enigma. It turned out to be the main cryptological weakness of the machine. Had Korn realized that, it would have been *much* harder to break it.

Comment: This is very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 6):

German Communists rather than the Nazis win power in Weimar Germany in 1920, and join the Soviet Union as equal partners, eventually coming to dominate the Communist Union. The combined Ruso-German behemoth spends the next 2 decades industrializing Russia and developing superb weapons and infrastructure. The western powers, demoralized after the extraordinarily steep recession, can only put up a token resistance in Europe, where strong Rsso-German intervention in Italy, Spain and France leads to communist regimes in those countries as well. In the late '30s, the Communist Behemoth sends millions of men and materiel  into China, turning it Red.

In 1941, the Communist Block launches a massive aerial and amphibious invasion of Britain, coinciding with a major strike across the army and transportation industry that paralyzes the country. London is taken in the first day. The country collapses in weeks.

Only America remains, separated by an ocean and its massive industrial infrastructure...

Comment: I (don't) like that variant. +1.

Comment: Your timing is a bit off; there where no Nazis (as such) till 1923. Do you instead propose that Socialists won the revolution of 1918/19?

Comment: Wow this never occurred to me. Just think with all those Jewish scientists still in Germany, what kind of tech they could have by 1945. It will be very interesting to explore how internal power struggles of Lenin, Stalin, and German leaders play out.

Answer (score 5):

First suggestion:

J. M. Stagg was the alliance meteorologist. In June 5, 1944, despite a storm along the French coast, Stagg insisted that conditions would improve. This was essentially a guess: that region's weather is so unstable that, even today with satellites, modern meteorologists have a 50% miss rate.

If the storm had not stopped, the alliance troops would have arrived at the coast in horrible conditions, wet, nauseated, in no condition to fight. In addition, there would have been no possibility of dropping paratroopers or bombs. The operation to free France would have failed.

Another change:

If, in 1941, Hitler had chosen to conquer Turkey--it would have been easy for Germany to do so--he might have started a campaign to extend German power across the Middle East, giving Hitler control over huge petroleum fields. After that, they could have begun the invasion of Russia by moving up from the southern Soviet Union, where the winter is not so harsh, thereby keeping Stalin away from his main petroleum sources.

After this, they could have conquered Russia and India. During that time, the Japanesese could have taken control over China, linking the axis powers across Asia. From that point, it would have been easy to dominate England, with its small population; indeed, without its colonial resources, it would certainly have been occupied. Keep this line of taking colonies in Africa and then you have control over Europe, Asia and Africa before 1950.

I think they would not stop. The German economy needed war. After 1950, it would be war between Germany and the USA for many years to come.

Comment: For Overlord, at that point of war, that Germany was going to be defeated was not a secret to anyone who knew the big picture. Overlord being a failure would probably just meant that the war would have lasted a little more, and the Soviet and Western armies would have met further West.

Comment: By the time of the Normandy landings, the Soviet armies were advancing through Poland at a fairly good speed.  [Operation Bagration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Bagration) and the [Lvov–Sandomierz Offensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lvov–Sandomierz_Offensive) were just about to begin.  If the landings failed, the only likely change would be an extra six months of war, ending with Soviet domination of *all* of Europe rather than just the eastern half.

Comment: I like the weather suggestion, but Turkey? 20M ppl, very mountainous terrain (much like Afghanistan), and they leaned to Axis already. Britain's Navy would surely supply the Turks and bog the German downs far more than they were in Southeast Europe (such as Crete). There is even a whole question on it on History.SE with many answers: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16806/why-didnt-germany-attack-turkey-during-ww2 (BTW, how you you propose Germany deliver the Middle East oil? And Russia **and** India? Very big countries, very big populations, very far from Germany. **Overextended.**)

Answer (score 5):

**The Japanese deliver their declaration of war to the USA *prior* to Pearl Harbor.**

In our timeline, administrative errors meant that the Japanese attacked Pearl Harbor prior to declaring war.

Had Japan declared war,  *and then immediately destroyed Pearl Harbor*, there would have been a devastating effect on the morale of the American citizenry and their politicians.

As it was, the negative impact on morale from the destruction at Pearl harbor was more than offset by the anger felt at the attack.

A demoralised USA may have continued to avoid being involved in WW2 in Europe.

This would be especially true if Germany had not declared war on the USA.

Note that the USA in our timeline does not join the war - it has war declared upon it.

Comment: Had war been declared in advance, the surprise attack would likely have been significantly less effective.

Comment: The plan was to deliver the declaration moments before the attack began, to prevent there being sufficient time for the American forces to prepare.  Which is one reason that the administrative errors caused it to move from "timely declaration" to a "late declaraion".

Comment: Not sure if I can endorse this idea. More negative morale would hurt for a time, but America had time to get over that before going on the true offensive around 1942 summer. Besides, the Doolittle raid would give a big boost in morale. I suggest putting the 3 carriers around Pearl Harbor **in Pearl Harbor** so that they are destroyed. That would at least drastically change the Pacific Theater for a few years. Could also let the 2 carriers of the risky Doolittle Raid get caught and sunk. That's 5.

Comment: The beginning of the war with Japan was mere formality - war was coming and everyone knew it. American efforts to actively hinder Japan made it a inevitable. Nothing would have turned Pearl Harbor from a rallying-cry into a cause to mope and withdraw, not even an Alamo level total defeat.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of interesting answers here but many of them require two or more major changes, not just one.  For example, a Nazi atomic weapon would have also required a delivery system, an "Amerika bomber", so that's two major changes. Also, developing an A-bomb would have required keeping the best scientific minds resident in Europe, an impossibility once Hitler started his anti-Semitic campaign.

A single change that was very doable using existing technology would have been to starve Great Britain out of the war by concentrating all available resources (u boats, aircraft, and ships) on the Battle of the Atlantic.  Eliminating Great Britain would have made it impossible for the Allies to carry out the strategic bombing campaign or stage the invasion.  No need to invade or occupy England, simply starve them to the point where they withdraw from the conflict.  Donitz possibly had just enough resources to accomplish this but Hitler kept sending U-boats to the Med on other missions instead of concentrating his forces on blockading GB.

On the flip side, the war might have been shortened considerably if the Allies had concentrated all their bombing efforts on petroleum resources instead of frittering away many aircraft and crews on ball bearing factory raids and other distractions.  German armament production remained steady (and even rose) during the entire war no matter how much they were bombed but once they ran out of oil the war was over.

Comment: Decent theory, but it too requires more than 1 change. After WW1, Germany was a ruined & poor country. By 1939, Germany only had about 50 U-Boats. This still did damage to Britain in the "first happy time" but they were adapting with better anti-sub warfare, and America was coming with liberty ships. BTW, in the original plan, Hitler never planned to invade Britain. He was shocked when Britain declared war. So the 1st chang: give Hitler this foresight and plan well ahead of time to siege Britain. But even if Germany amassed 100+ subs by 1939, they could not have done it secretly.

Comment: German U-boats and ships were concentrated on the Battle of the Atlantic.
However, they lost it.
It's also hard to see how the Germans could have concentrated much more air power on the Battle of the Atlantic.

I agree, that, had the Germans had the capability to win the Battle of the Atlantic, it would have been a great idea for them to win it.
But the reason they lost it was because U-boats only had a short period where they were dominantly effective, and the German Navy's surface vessels were successfully kept penned up by the Royal Navy for pretty much the entire time.

Answer (score 4):

- Japan acting according to the plan.
  The plan for Japan was to attack the east coast of Russia, instead of the USA. The failure to do so caused two devastating consequences: It enabled the USA to join the war, and it freed the forces in eastern Russia to fight on the western front causing massive trouble for the german forces.
  Japan attacked the US instead of Russia mostly because they needed fuel. So to ensure the attack on Russia in your alternate reality have germany invest heavily in coal-to-liquid, some tankers, and ship lots of fuel to japan pre war.
- Win the Battle of Britain.
  The german air force could have one air superiority over England, but failed for two main reasons:
  They used the V1 and V2 on civilian targets instead of air fields, and they did not realize how much they were hurting the british air force by targeting the radar. By wining air superiority over England an invasion would have been possible, preventing the allies from bombing germany and invading in france

Comment: By the time the V1 and V2 entered the war, Germany had long since lost the Battle of Britain.

Comment: The Battle of Britain -- a battle for strategic air superiority over the channel in order to stand off the Royal Navy so a crossing could be made, forcing England out of the war -- had nothing to do with the V1 / V2, which were "Vergeltungswaffen" and of very little strategic value. If anything, different fighter tactics could have made a difference in BoB. Forcing the Me-109 to fly close bomber escort robbed them of initiative in aerial combat. Giving them free hand to fly *above* the bomber formations, entering combat at an energy advantage, *could* have made a change.

Comment: As for Germany shipping fuel to Japan... Germany *did* invest heavily (and I mean *heavily*) in coal-to-liquid, and still wasn't able to meet its own demands, let alone *exporting* any.

Comment: There was no consulting on plans between Germany and Japan.

Answer (score 2):

Single change: No radar available.

Without it United Kingdom would not have the tool to fight agaist Germany neither during the Battle of Britain nor the Battle of Atlantic.
Hence UK would have been invaded and USA would not have the chance to cross the Atlantic to help. Leaving the Soviet Union alone.

Comment: Successfully invading Britain would have cost the Germans a lot more casualties, so they would've invaded USSR with significantly less reserves, reserves that would be desperately needed by 1942/1943. Invading and occupying Britain for a time probably would have delayed Barbarossa too unless they decided to ignore Yugoslavia and Balkan Campaign.

Comment: @DrZ214. After Dunkirk UK army almost did not have weapons to cause high casualties during the invasion. But even if Germany delayed Barbarossa to 1942 they would have had a huge army, because no defenses were needed in the west. Yugoslavia and Balkan campaign would not have existed with UK defeated.

Answer (score 2):

**Honor the Molotov–Ribbentrop Pact**

Stalin was afraid of Hitler and Germany which was reflected in orders to avoid antagonizing the Germans and to give generous trade concessions.  Stalin even considered a full alliance with Hitler in dividing up Europe and Asia.  Stalin hesitated only because Hitler actually thought Britain was a more desirable ally.  However, Hitler does not have that prejudice in this timeline.

Hitler and Stalin divide up Europe and Asia.  This allows Germany to put all resources into invading England.  Russian troops move into the Middle East and South Asia, occupying the majority of British and French possessions.  The destruction of the British Empire allows Japan to rapidly expand into the South Pacific probably without the need to attack Pearl Harbor since the British Fleet would be defending the home island.

America now sees the hopelessness of defending Europe and reinforces its isolationist positions.

Even if Pearl Harbor happened, the US would quickly sue for peace with three major power navies to have to defend against.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact_negotiations

Answer (score 1):

The only real hope the Germany had was to not attack the USSR and to either not declare war on the US after the Japanese attack on Pearl Harbor or to have Japan not attack the US at all.

After the fall of France, Germany had the potential to be an economic power on the same scale as the US. Hitler refused to sit back and rationalize the economy. Germany went to war against the USSR unprepared to fight a long war. They either won with a short decisive victory using a superbly trained, semi-mechanized army or they would get sucked into a multi-front war of attrition that would likely lead to Germany's defeat.

In addition, Germany's decision to declare war on the US after Pearl Harbor was a gift to those in US Gov who wanted to prioritize the destruction of Nazi Germany.

The Japanese decision to go to war against the US was foolish. The Japanese went to war to secure natural resources - especially oil. They saw the US military presence in the Philippines as a possible barrier to their expansion. The Japanese could have attacked the Dutch East Indies and ignored the Philippines. Before the war, the US military had come to the conclusion that they could not defend the Philippines.

Comment: Attacking the USSR was the *point* of the war.

Answer (score 1):

What if the German strategy from 1930s onward had been to focus on the resources needed for a sustained war, Oil/Ore/Coal/Food, rather than to focus on the peoples/politics of Europe.  Germany actually prepared to win WWI again, but better, rather than thinking about the next steps beyond a German breakout.

If the German plan had been to focus on Russia and Finland, they could have capture all the resources they need, whilst leaving mainland Europe alone.  If they hadn't attacked France/BENELUX they may have been able to come to an agreement with Britain, and had peace in Europe, having gained the border with Russia that they needed.  Then they could have applied Blitzkrieg to Ukraine/Russia, at the start of spring 1940, before the Russians had managed to ramp up their far eastern industry.  If they'd managed to capture the oil fields of the caucuses, and the coal fields of eastern Ukraine, and the naval base in the Crimea, they would have then been in a far better position to Ally with Turkey and Italy to control the Mediterranean, whilst maintaining a constant land based supply of resources.  Conquering mainland Europe really gained them nothing strategically, beyond shoring up the defence of the Fatherland.

As Sun Tzu said, avoid cities.  Well Europe was one big city, by working around it, they could have controlled the world.

Comment: Hitler didn't start the war with France/England. They declared war on him, because of Poland gamble. At the start it was a phony war, but France/England would turn it hot after some time. How to invade Russia without conquering Poland?

Comment: The posture germany had adopted by 1939 faced west, france/britain declared war over poland because it was a further sign of german intent. If Germany had followed the same strategy in poland that it had done in Czechoslovakia, my fomenting an uprising then 'going in to protect threatened germans' (much like the russians are doing today), would have makes it almost impossible for uk/france to declare. Only arrogance allowed the out/out invasion on poland, forced a war that was not neccesary at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Fascinating answers on this question.  I'll throw a few small twigs on the fire.

Idea 1.  Hitler attacks Russia first.  Most of the western powers weren't excited about either Stalin or Hitler.  Had Hitler started on Russia in 1939, there would not have been time to move the factories, no supplies to Murmansk, and a single front war.

The key here would be to grab a rail line deep into Russia, and keep it.

Follow that up with a grab for the oil in the middle east.

Idea #2 Build submarines, not battleships.  Ship building is close to linear per ton.  A Class 7 Uboat is 700 tons.  A Bismark class battleship is 40,000 tons.  Heavy cruisers are abut 10,000 tons.   Same effort could have added 200 more subs.

The Kreigsmarine were already worried enough about their code machines that they moved to a 4 rotor version.  Had they been a bit more paranoid, and gone to 5 rotor one, changed the settings more than once per day, and picked the 5 from a larger set of rotors total, then decoding would have been far more difficult.

Idea #3  One of the ways the allies got a lead on a sub was through radio direction finding.   Consider the invention of the "Cry Wolf"  This is a bouy with a timer, a battery and a radio.  Every now and then it broadcasts a stream of giberish that is similar to a code broadcast.  The Radio DF on it, but there is only a buoy there.  Cheap to make, hard to spot.  Could waste a lot of resources sending planes to check them.

Idea #4.  The german's acoustic torpedo wasn't sensitive enough to hear slow moving ships.  Modify the torpedo so that its speed isn't constant.  It runs X yards on launch, then slows down to listen, gets a bearing on the noisiest target, sprints for a thousand yards, slows again. Various actions could be set by a device much like the works in a fancy coo-coo clock, with a music box drum to control timing.

A slower torpedo has a longer range. The G7 had a range of just under 6 km at 24 knots. Drag goes up with the cube of speed.  Convoys weren't fast.  A torpedo that was launched from in front of the convoy and set to 'travel at 15 foot depth a 6 knots for 30 minutes (about 6 km. At 1/4 speed, it's battery is almost untouched) then go active.    Active sonar wasn't very effective for an object close to the surface.  And a slow torpedo wasn't going to be very noisy for passive sensors.

Answer (score 1):

A forgotten tipping point is the [battle of Bir-Hakeim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Bir_Hakeim), in May/June 1942. The British not sending the 1st Free French Brigade may have had dramatic consequences for the entire war.

In 1942, the British Eighth Army and the German Panzerarmee Afrika are rushing to take position and gain control of North Africa. The British need to reach El Alamein to stand a chance, but Rommel's forces is going to arrive there too soon. So they sent a small force to engage in delaying actions. Namely, they sent the 1st Free French Brigade, under General Kœnig (yes, this is a French name - from Alsace, in fact, for extra irony), which was at this point pretty much the entire Free French regular army.

For several weeks, Kœnig's entrenched men held against the Panzerarmee Afrika. Then, after buying enough time for the British forces to take position, they punched through the Axis siege and managed to escape with half of the initial forces.

The following clash of El Alamein would be hard fought, and ultimately result in a British victory.

Now, **what if the British had sent another force**, one that would not have held as well and buy enough time for the Eighth Army? What if the subsequent Battle of probably-somewhere-else-than-El Alamein result in a British defeat?

First, the Allied morale suffers a harsh blow, instead of a huge boon. The German are still victorious, battle after battle. That won't be enough to knock Britain out of the war, but it will weaken its war effort. It may possibly weaken American support before Pearl Harbour, with dramatic consequences for the British.

Second, there is no spectacular Free French victory to give them much needed recognition. The Vichy regime is still the internationally recognised French government, and the Allied will futilly continue trying to talk with it instead of relying on the Free French.

So no Free French army to speak of. The absence (and even worse, opposition) of the elite French Alpine troops would be felt during mountain battles. French Resistance is divided, weakened by Communist Resistance betrayals, and the Vichy regime has more support. No General Leclerc, depriving the Allied from one of their best generals. Worse, the French colonial empire doesn't switch to the Allies. In addition to facing the entrenched Axis forces, invading French North Africa will be a serious challenge.

With Britain and French Resistance weakened, landings in Normandy and later Provence will be much more difficult, if they are attempted at all. The Aquitaine region won't liberate itself, nor will Paris. Festung Europa holds.

Axis forces holding North Africa alleviates one of the biggest problems they historically faced: oil shortage.

So a stronger, oil-supplied Germany is attacking the Soviet Union. Enough to make a difference? Possibly. Even through the Soviet Union still had colossal manpower reserves and an immense territory to retreat to, a more successful operation Barbarossa may have reached vital rail centres and/or oil fields, preventing the Soviet to efficiently counter-attack.

Germany would still be over-extended, lacking many resources, with an inefficient long-term economy policy and constant political infighting in its administration, opposed by an industrial giant protected by two oceans and facing Resistances all over its occupied territories.

It would not have survived for very long.

But technically, it would have won the war.

Answer (score -2):

U.S. Carriers were in port on Dec. 7th and were mostly destroyed with the rest of the Capitol ships in the 7th fleet.

The morale boost gained by Doolittle's raid would never have happened.

Midway would have been lost.

Japanese invasion of Hawaii more likely.

Hard to say if this would have changed the outcome.  Delayed it certainly.

Comment: The US had lost all its carriers but one by 1943.  The building program produced some 8 more and then dozens per year after that.  Losing the carriers makes the early campaigns less active, but Japan had little capability to mount major sustained offensives much farther out than they did.  This includes invading Hawaii, Australia or the West Coast.

Comment: All that would have done would be lengthen the war, not give Japan a victory.  America's ridiculously greater productive ability meant that Japan had lost the Pacific war the second the first bomb fell at Pearl Harbor.  Roosevelt made the conscious decision to put 90% of the effort into defeating Germany, the Pacific got the scraps.  And yet even with that, just look up the number of Essex class fleet carriers we were able to crank out over the war years.  Then compare it to the number of fleet carriers the Japanese were able to build.  Just that one stat will show you it was no contest.

Comment: Between the attack on Pearl Harbor and the Japanese surrender, the United States commissioned 26 fleet and light fleet aircraft carriers, with another 14 under construction.  Loss of the carriers would have been annoying, and probably would have drawn the war out by a year or so, but would hardly have been fatal.